# Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

While benchmarking something I measured a much lower throughput than I had calculated, which I narrowed down to the LZCNT instruction (it also happens with TZCNT), as demonstrated in the following benchmarks:

```
  xor ecx, ecx
_benchloop:
  lzcnt eax, edx
  add ecx, 1
  jnz _benchloop
```

And:

```
  xor ecx, ecx
_benchloop:
  xor eax, eax  ; this shouldn't help, but it does
  lzcnt eax, edx
  add ecx, 1
  jnz _benchloop
```

The second version is much faster. It shouldn't be. There's no reason why LZCNT should have an input dependency on its output. Unlike BSR/BSF, the xZCNT instructions *always* overwrite their output.

I'm running this on a 4770K, so LZCNT and TZCNT aren't being executed as BSR/BSF.

What's going on here?

Comment: Perhaps `lzcnt` can't be executed speculatively (it updates CF, ZF) *after* `jnz` (ZF != 0). Whereas `xor` breaks the dependency chain? But since `add` would retire the previous flags anyway, I'm not if this is the case.

Comment: Just to make sure: can you rule out that it is a code alignment issue and has nothing to do with lzcnt?

Comment: @PhiS using a 3 byte `nop` instead of `xor eax, eax` made it slow again

Comment: The "xor" workaround has been added to gcc 4.9.2: https://gcc.gnu.org/PR62011

Comment: For reference by future visitors, this is just microarchitectural errata (essentially, a bug). There is no reason why `LZCNT` should have an input dependency on its output, but it does. The `POPCNT` instruction has the same bug, as described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-count-variable-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance/25089720#25089720).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is simply a limitation in the micro-architecture of your Intel Haswell CPU and several previous<sup>1</sup> CPUs. It has been fixed for `tzcnt` and `lzcnt` as of Skylake-S (client), but the issue remained for `popcnt` until it was fixed in Cannon Lake.

On those micro-architectures the destination operand for `tzcnt`, `lzcnt` and `popcnt` is treated as an input dependency even though, semantically, it is not. Now I doubt this is a really a "bug": if it was simply an unintended behavior/oversight, I expect it would have been fixed in one of the several new micro-architectures that have been released since it was introduced.

Most likely it is a design compromise based on one or both of the following two factors:

- The hardware for `popcnt`, `lzcnt` and `tzcnt` is [likely all shared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803917/149138) with the existing `bsf` and `bsr` instructions. Now `bsf` and `bsr` *do* have a dependency on the previous destination value *in practice*<sup>2</sup> for the special case of all-bits-zero input, since Intel chips leave the destination unmodified in that case. So it is entirely possible that the simplest design for the combined hardware resulted in the other similar instructions executing on the same unit inheriting the same dependency.
- The vast majority of x86 two operand ALU instructions have an dependency on the destination operand, since it is used as a source as well. The three affected instructions are somewhat unique in that they are *unary* operators, but unlike existing unary operators like `not` and `neg` which have a single operand used as source and destination, they have distinct source and destination operands, making them superficially similar to most 2-input instructions. Perhaps the renamer/scheduler circuitry just doesn't distinguish the special case of these unary-with-two-register-operand versus the vast majority of plain shared source/destination 2-input instructions which don't have this dependency.

In fact, for the case of `popcnt` Intel has issued various errata covering the false dependency issue such as [HSD146](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-specification-update.pdf) for Haswell Desktop and SKL029 for [Skylake](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/specification-updates/desktop-6th-gen-core-family-spec-update.pdf), which reads:

> **POPCNT Instruction May Take Longer to Execute Than Expected**
>
> **Problem** POPCNT instruction execution with a 32 or 64 bit operand may be
> delayed until  previous non -dependent instructions have executed.
>
> **Implication** Software using the POPCNT instruction may experience lower performance than  expected.
>
> **Workaround** None identified

I always found this erratum unusual since it isn't really identifying any type of functional defect or non-conformance to specification which is the case for essentially all the other errata. Intel doesn't really document a specific performance model for the OoO execution engine and there are a ton of other performance "gotchas" that have appeared and disappeared over the years (many with a much larger impact than this very minor issue) that don't get documented in errata. Still, this perhaps provides some evidence that it can be considered a bug. Oddly, the erratum was never extended to include `tzcnt` or `lzcnt` which had the same issue when they were introduced.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well `tzcnt` and `lzcnt` only appeared in Haswell, but the problem exists for `popcnt` as well which was introduced in Nehalem - but the false dependency problem [perhaps only exists](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62011) for Sandy Bridge or later.

<sup>2</sup> *In practice*, although not documented in the ISA docs, since the result for all-zero input was undefined in the Intel manuals. Most or all Intel chips implemented the behavior as leaving the destination register unchanged in this case, however.
[AMD *does* document](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf#page=157) and guarantee that behaviour for `bsf` and `bsr`.

(But unfortunately those instructions are slower than `tzcnt`/`lzcnt`
on AMD (extra uops, see https://uops.info/), so instead of taking advantage of that `bsf` behaviour, it would often be better for AMD CPUs to use `rep bsf` so it will decode as `tzcnt` on CPUs that know about that instruction, and `test`/`cmov` if you have enough free registers.  But `bsr` gives different results to `lzcnt` even for non-zero input, so you might consider taking advantage of it.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158783/discussion-between-beeonrope-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: The dst-unmodified behaviour of BSF/BSR *is* documented by AMD ISA reference, for AMD CPUs.  I expect future Intel will continue to be compatible with AMD and current Intel CPUs in future, almost certainly for uarches that evolve out of their current Sandybridge-family (e.g. Ice Lake).  Plausible that they'd drop the output dependency for that execution unit in a wholly new uarch, especially if backwards compat isn't as much of a priority (e.g. if they ever do something like KNL again)

Comment: @PeterCordes do you by any chance have a link to the BSF/BSR documentation in AMD ISA? I am having trouble finding it.

Comment: @Noah: https://developer.amd.com/resources/developer-guides-manuals/ was the first hit on google for `amd x86 manual`.  Since this is not specific to one uarch, on that page look for the "AMD64 Architecture" manuals, and it seems vol.3 is the "general" instructions, not simd or fp.  Equivalent of Intel's vol.2 SDM manual.  https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/24594.pdf#page=157 is the entry for BSF which mentions that src=0 case.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Differences_between_AMD64_and_Intel_64 I think says the whole reg is truly unmodified even for 32-bit operand-size.)

Answer (score 4):

Along the lines of what @BrettHale suggested, it's possible (if odd) that you're hitting a corner-case partial flags update stall. The flag state should in theory simply be renamed away because the following add updates all flags, but if it isn't for some reason then it would introduce a loop-carried dependency, and inserting xor would break that dependency.

It's hard to know for certain if this is what's happening, but it looks at a casual glance to be the most likely explanation; you can test the hypothesis by replacing the `xor` with `test` (which also breaks the flags dependency but has no effect on register dependencies).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It was a good theory, but unfortunately the test disproves it. After changing the `xor` to `test`, it went back to being slow.

Comment: @harold: Nothing unfortunate about it.  You seem to have ruled out alignment, and we’ve just ruled out a partial flags dependency.  “When you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.”  We’ve may not quite have eliminated everything else yet, but it looks increasingly like xZCNT as implemented on your processor has a dependency on its output register in rename.

Comment: What else should I test, before I draw that conclusion?

Comment: @StephenCanon: This is in fact the case.  It's a performance bug in Intel CPUs.  Now that this is known, gcc tries to work around it by using an output register that hasn't been used recently.  google should be able to find some hits.  IDK when it was discovered; maybe not until after this Q&A.