# Count leading zeros in __m256i word

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm tinkering around with AVX-2 instructions and I'm looking for a fast way to count the number of leading zeros in a `__m256i` word (which has 256 bits).

So far, I have figured out the following way:

```
// Computes the number of leading zero bits.
// Here, avx_word is of type _m256i.

if (!_mm256_testz_si256(avx_word, avx_word)) {
  uint64_t word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 0);
  if (word > 0)
    return (__builtin_clzll(word));

  word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 1);
  if (word > 0)
    return (__builtin_clzll(word) + 64);

  word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 2);
  if (word > 0)
    return (__builtin_clzll(word) + 128);

  word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 3);
  return (__builtin_clzll(word) + 192);
} else
  return 256; // word is entirely zero
```

However, I find it rather clumsy to figure out the exact non-zero word within the 256 bit register.

Does anybody know if there is a more elegant (or faster) way to do this?

Just as an additional information:
I actually want to compute the index of the first set bit for arbitrarily long vectors created by logical ANDs, and I am comparing the performance of standard 64 bit operations with SSE and AVX-2 code.
Here is my entire test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdalign.h>

#define ALL  0xFFFFFFFF
#define NONE 0x0


#define BV_SHIFTBITS ((size_t)    6)
#define BV_MOD_WORD  ((size_t)   63)
#define BV_ONE       ((uint64_t)  1)
#define BV_ZERO      ((uint64_t)  0)
#define BV_WORDSIZE  ((uint64_t) 64)


uint64_t*
Vector_new(
    size_t num_bits) {

  assert ((num_bits % 256) == 0);
  size_t num_words = num_bits >> BV_SHIFTBITS;
  size_t mod = num_bits & BV_MOD_WORD;
  if (mod > 0)
    assert (0);
  uint64_t* words;
  posix_memalign((void**) &(words), 32, sizeof(uint64_t) * num_words);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; ++i)
    words[i] = 0;
  return words;
}


void
Vector_set(
    uint64_t* vector,
    size_t pos) {

  const size_t word_index = pos >> BV_SHIFTBITS;
  const size_t offset     = pos & BV_MOD_WORD;
  vector[word_index] |= (BV_ONE << (BV_MOD_WORD - offset));
}


size_t
Vector_and_first_bit(
    uint64_t** vectors,
    const size_t num_vectors,
    const size_t num_words) {

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_words; ++i) {
    uint64_t word = vectors[0][i];
    for (size_t j = 1; j < num_vectors; ++j)
      word &= vectors[j][i];
    if (word > 0)
      return (1 + i * BV_WORDSIZE + __builtin_clzll(word));
  }
  return 0;
}


size_t
Vector_and_first_bit_256(
    uint64_t** vectors,
    const size_t num_vectors,
    const size_t num_avx_words) {

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_avx_words; ++i) {
    const size_t addr_offset = i << 2;
    __m256i avx_word = _mm256_load_si256(
        (__m256i const*) (vectors[0] + addr_offset));

    // AND the AVX words
    for (size_t j = 1; j < num_vectors; ++j) {
      avx_word = _mm256_and_si256(
        avx_word,
        _mm256_load_si256((__m256i const*) (vectors[j] + addr_offset))
      );
    }

    // test whether resulting AVX word is not zero
    if (!_mm256_testz_si256(avx_word, avx_word)) {
      uint64_t word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 0);
      const size_t shift = i << 8;
      if (word > 0)
        return (1 + shift + __builtin_clzll(word));

      word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 1);
      if (word > 0)
        return (1 + shift + __builtin_clzll(word) + 64);

      word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 2);
      if (word > 0)
        return (1 + shift + __builtin_clzll(word) + 128);

      word = _mm256_extract_epi64(avx_word, 3);
      return (1 + shift + __builtin_clzll(word) + 192);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


size_t
Vector_and_first_bit_128(
    uint64_t** vectors,
    const size_t num_vectors,
    const size_t num_avx_words) {

  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_avx_words; ++i) {
    const size_t addr_offset = i << 1;
    __m128i avx_word = _mm_load_si128(
        (__m128i const*) (vectors[0] + addr_offset));

    // AND the AVX words
    for (size_t j = 1; j < num_vectors; ++j) {
      avx_word = _mm_and_si128(
        avx_word,
        _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*) (vectors[j] + addr_offset))
      );
    }

    // test whether resulting AVX word is not zero
    if (!_mm_test_all_zeros(avx_word, avx_word)) {
      uint64_t word = _mm_extract_epi64(avx_word, 0);
      if (word > 0)
        return (1 + (i << 7) + __builtin_clzll(word));

      word = _mm_extract_epi64(avx_word, 1);
      return (1 + (i << 7) + __builtin_clzll(word) + 64);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}


uint64_t*
make_random_vector(
    const size_t num_bits,
    const size_t propability) {

  uint64_t* vector = Vector_new(num_bits);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_bits; ++i) {
    const int x = rand() % 10;
    if (x >= (int) propability)
      Vector_set(vector, i);
  }
  return vector;
}


size_t
millis(
    const struct timeval* end,
    const struct timeval* start) {

  struct timeval e = *end;
  struct timeval s = *start;
  return (1000 * (e.tv_sec - s.tv_sec) + (e.tv_usec - s.tv_usec) / 1000);
}


int
main(
    int argc,
    char** argv) {

  if (argc != 6)
    printf("fuck %s\n", argv[0]);

  srand(time(NULL));

  const size_t num_vectors = atoi(argv[1]);
  const size_t size = atoi(argv[2]);
  const size_t num_iterations = atoi(argv[3]);
  const size_t num_dimensions = atoi(argv[4]);
  const size_t propability = atoi(argv[5]);
  const size_t num_words = size / 64;
  const size_t num_sse_words = num_words / 2;
  const size_t num_avx_words = num_words / 4;

  assert(num_vectors > 0);
  assert(size > 0);
  assert(num_iterations > 0);
  assert(num_dimensions > 0);

  struct timeval t1;
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);

  uint64_t*** vectors = (uint64_t***) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t**) * num_vectors);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_vectors; ++j) {
    vectors[j] = (uint64_t**) malloc(sizeof(uint64_t*) * num_dimensions);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_dimensions; ++i)
      vectors[j][i] = make_random_vector(size, propability);
  }

  struct timeval t2;
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  printf("Creation: %zu ms\n", millis(&t2, &t1));



  size_t* results_64    = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t) * num_vectors);
  size_t* results_128   = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t) * num_vectors);
  size_t* results_256   = (size_t*) malloc(sizeof(size_t) * num_vectors);


  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_iterations; ++j)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vectors; ++i)
      results_64[i] = Vector_and_first_bit(vectors[i], num_dimensions,
          num_words);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  const size_t millis_64 = millis(&t2, &t1);
  printf("64            : %zu ms\n", millis_64);


  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_iterations; ++j)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vectors; ++i)
      results_128[i] = Vector_and_first_bit_128(vectors[i],
          num_dimensions, num_sse_words);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  const size_t millis_128 = millis(&t2, &t1);
  const double factor_128 = (double) millis_64 / (double) millis_128;
  printf("128           : %zu ms (factor: %.2f)\n", millis_128, factor_128);

  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_iterations; ++j)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vectors; ++i)
      results_256[i] = Vector_and_first_bit_256(vectors[i],
          num_dimensions, num_avx_words);
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  const size_t millis_256 = millis(&t2, &t1);
  const double factor_256 = (double) millis_64 / (double) millis_256;
  printf("256           : %zu ms (factor: %.2f)\n", millis_256, factor_256);


  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_vectors; ++i) {
    if (results_64[i] != results_256[i])
      printf("ERROR: %zu (64) != %zu (256) with i = %zu\n", results_64[i],
          results_256[i], i);
    if (results_64[i] != results_128[i])
      printf("ERROR: %zu (64) != %zu (128) with i = %zu\n", results_64[i],
          results_128[i], i);
  }


  free(results_64);
  free(results_128);
  free(results_256);

  for (size_t j = 0; j < num_vectors; ++j) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_dimensions; ++i)
      free(vectors[j][i]);
    free(vectors[j]);
  }
  free(vectors);
  return 0;
}
```

To compile:

```
gcc -o main main.c -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -Werror -march=native -std=c99 -fno-tree-vectorize
```

To execute:

```
./main 1000 8192 50000 5 9
```

The parameters mean: 1000 testcases, vectors of length 8192 bits, 50000, test repetitions (last two parameters are minor tweaks).

Sample output for the above call on my machine:

```
Creation: 363 ms
64            : 15000 ms
128           : 10070 ms (factor: 1.49)
256           : 6784 ms (factor: 2.21)
```

Comment: Is throughput or latency most important here?  Are you doing this for just one vector, or is it useful to lzcount multiple vectors in parallel.  (No specific idea in mind, but branchy vs. branchless could be better.  And for throughput, store / reload can be better than `vpextrq`, especially because extracting from the high 128 is impossible with one instruction; `vpextrq` only works on `xmm` registers, so `_mm256_extract_epi64(vec, 3)` would need a `vextracti128 xmm0, ymm1, 1` first.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your *input* values are uniformly distributed, almost all of the time the highest set bit will be in the top 64 bits of the vector (1 in 2^64).  A branch on this condition will predict very well.  [@Nejc's answer is good for that case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213611/count-leading-zeros-in-m256i-word/49216086#49216086).

But many problems where `lzcnt` is part of the solution have more uniformly distributed *output*, where it's common for the highest set bit to be somewhere other than the highest 64 bits.

---

Wim's idea of `lzcnt` on a compare bitmap to find the right element is a very good approach.

However, **runtime-variable indexing of the vector with a store/reload is probably better than a shuffle**.  Store-forwarding latency is low (maybe 5 to 7 cycles on Skylake), and some of that latency is in parallel with the index generation (compare / movemask / lzcnt).  The `movd/vpermd/movd` lane-crossing shuffle strategy takes 7 cycles on Skylake to get the right element into an integer register, only starting after the index is known.  Load-use latency for an L1d cache hit is only 5 cycles from address to data, probably similar when data comes from the store buffer.  ([4c only in pointer-chasing scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52351397/is-there-a-penalty-when-baseoffset-is-in-a-different-page-than-the-base)).  See http://agner.org/optimize/, and especially https://uops.info/ which has latency measurements for `movd`.  If you look at the [details](https://uops.info/html-lat/SKL/MOVD_XMM_R32-Measurements.html), one of the measurements is for a round-trip chain of movd to/from xmm0.  On Haswell it's 2 cycles per round trip, so 5 total with a `vpermd` in between.  On Skylake, a `movd` round trip has 4 cycle latency, presumably 3 cycles one way, 1 the other, so 7 cycles with `vpermd`.

**I think this version should be better or equal latency on Haswell/Skylake, and also better throughput.  Much better on Ryzen**.  (`vpermd` is slower than Intel on Zen before Zen 4. And a `movd` round-trip on Zen 4 is about 7 cycles, with one of the `movd` instructions being 2 uops.  6 cycle round-trip on Zen 2 and 3 with single-uop `movd`.)

Some scalar math is needed on an `lzcnt` result to get a load index, which eats into the latency and throughput advantage some, depending on how clever the compiler is.  `lzcnt` on a `vmovmskps` result works directly as a shuffle index for `vpermd`.

Aligning the stack by 32 avoids cache-line splits on a 32-byte store, but it takes extra instructions.  So this is best if it can inline into a function that uses it multiple times, or already needs that much alignment for some other `__m256i`.  GCC will align the stack whether you ask for it or not, but MSVC and Clang won't.  Store-forwarding from a dword aligned relative to the store works even if the store itself is a cache-line split on most modern CPUs, I think.

```
static inline
int lzcnt_si256(__m256i vec)
{
    // or just lzcnt_si256_memsrc(&vec) optimizes away store/reload
    __m256i   vnonzero = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(vec, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    uint32_t  nzmask = ~ _mm256_movemask_epi8(vnonzero);   //  1 for bytes that are part of non-zero dwords
    // nzmask |= 0xf;  // branchless clamp to last elem
    if (nzmask == 0)     // all 32 bits came from vpmovmskb, so NOT didn't introduce any constant 1s
        return 256;      // don't access outside the array
    alignas(32) uint32_t elems[8];
    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)elems, vec);

    unsigned  lzbytes = _lzcnt_u32(nzmask);   // bytes above the dword containing the nonzero bit.
    unsigned char *end_elem = 28 + (unsigned char*)elems;
    uint32_t *nz_elem = (uint32_t*)(end_elem - lzbytes);  // idx = 31-(lzcnt+3) = 28-lzcnt
    return    8*lzbytes + _lzcnt_u32(*nz_elem);  // this is an aligned load, memcpy not needed
}

// unaligned and strict-aliasing safe
static inline
int lzcnt_si256_memsrc(const void *m256)
{
    __m256i  vec = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)m256);
    __m256i  vnonzero = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(vec, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    uint32_t nzmask = ~ _mm256_movemask_epi8(vnonzero);
    // nzmask |= 0xf;  // branchless clamp to last elem
    if (nzmask == 0)    // all 32 bits came from vpmovmskb, so NOT didn't introduce any constant 1s
        return 256;     // don't access outside the array

    unsigned  lzbytes = _lzcnt_u32(nzmask);
    unsigned char *end_elem = 28 + (unsigned char*)m256;  // can be done as part of the addressing mode after sub
    uint32_t *nz_elem = (uint32_t*)(end_elem - lzbytes);  // idx = MSB_idx-3 = 31-(lzcnt+3) = 28-lzcnt
    uint32_t nz_dword;
    memcpy(&nz_dword, nz_elem, sizeof(nz_dword));  // For strict-aliasing safety,  and/or if m256 wasn't aligned by 4.  __attribute__((aligned(1),may_alias)) on the pointer would work in GNU C
    return    8*lzbytes + _lzcnt_u32(nz_dword);
}
```

GCC and clang don't optimize away the `storeu` copy if the vector was just loaded, so I made a separate version, unfortunately.  (If your data isn't 4-byte aligned and you're getting cache-line splits on the dword load as well as the vector load, consider using the byte version that loads with `movzx`.)

[On Godbolt with GCC13 `-O3 -march=x86-64-v3`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCCSXKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BekkpjgJBIeEsUTFxtpj2eQxCBEzEBBk%2BfvF2mA5pNXUEBWGR0bEttfWNWYNdPUUlAwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CarbgoE%2BKgAdAh72CYaAIJrG1uYu/uH%2BIJnF1e3ZusMm147ezceBYLGCBGIwXeq0uNzuvweTwO4OCwChMNusO%2BeCoDCwVG2AH0ALJCNwEgBq2AASp84X8Ac8jmI8MAGGjttsAPScknktzbPAKbaghQpIzbAgIQV7ABin2522uuO26FQmAUDDAHAI2wUXgSSXqhOutBZzCFwW2/JYGEwJ22FkwBAI0V1jmQAGsJagrdZrNsAO6EBACggnWnfVzY2k3bmHJjugUMU0hT5g7a0ABeyEEBJSZgArAA2CAEgksQtFvDbABubWmtIA7FYbhyOQqSNttF5Dhns7n88Xy5gWApFhBzEW68hpttUAlHKDM%2BrtkwA0wAJ5ukiYTnECqoJjoT5twnlyvVjk1hgCZfEH17AAihJBlYJyBYCUwAEcCZgEngqxmBA06kC%2BFZDkoBB3qgeZ4JWEDTA2qwttcp5eGCQEEjq2wMJmLBMAoXpPtsAB%2B4FvjadYEURf4AQAHCBN54dEqDIRYbYKtsXDbPwxDbBEG4ukKkoJqu%2B7bAkXRzvizEALQwSqAYkOgCgnpxnK4fhhHEY2bgkRoqhUHsHFcppETEIYyAIPQorbJsrAJN6GaETqFQjupHLYtsEB4TRxGrI%2BBmzqeCpiLQ2xAQJhBCqIbC8feLC1gkVGjh6ERgQoPqhAA8gAKiqeDoJq2pJuCGBeEsq4MFuaAMPGgjcWpranm2%2B4EAsDDbJWJmtWZKoCFqOpMMgSx2fMBApDskqPHUlkbp5q6mqyhEQEBs4YYIWFufQo4mAWFj0ftQUoYt5YQUWeZEPuXhwQhpbnsWeAAFTTO5o5gdO7ExmhbZePVZqYOgHJZoJwlPM%2BBJZjmBAEl4QG%2BdpRHsRpAlCSuTARKgdYSggjzoMpxDA3VtTBCiuOPMxikRIQ4YtRy/0pKyQP2QgdTbM9rh/rtEPdfRuyWD5jOA8TbPEK971qad9PbJtBDbRzeHcyOvMQHL22vRAXPvdscl9mD6oo/1RWqLzqxcHJEDQ4I1irLOJFmPRcnWwQi3tZ1p70c9oPo0K/pQ/2sPw8Bz1K%2B9RsKpKgoCkKhhLSLGaHugYFsCwyAJFuN46iEQNA02QWwrGmn/cyzPA4YwOHBCDhycyhHkwoTBUJg8qcvGibBCmLc3OmLt3UOqdjsgEB1b2NaoEVHMXQ2sLNmdj1VlebS8%2Bdb60Ent2DiWI8CL2ZYXS90zTyZ88H1eVOsSvr5Dh%2BX6/v%2BgHAaBFGQU6MH9yWSEnzL6tmNhWn%2BV5uRVeA9sYjh0nRPAjFry3lYt9GWCo/I6V2HpAyRler9QslZGy6pYoGE/M5AwvZ3qLW8ojQBT5gqhU0uFSKZhoqTXsqwR4VBErJVSkRDKupsr5UKsVIaZV7zoEqrNGq9ld61EalwZqv0%2Bru2IF1HqKFWoKlVCVYao1cFzi8JNIqjwZriXmj9dCAMy4g0zAbP2gVCR92DuQnS8DZGy1MSEUW7NOa4mVklB2/N/RqxcSzaydRXoXQwQqUQXUogDRCKuIUUkjSoHxAYo86B9yinJjaHYTcXT8T1BERav9/6h0zF41WhSCCa21jzPWPthIR00ibXmJILAEhNnJVYZsLZW0Drbe21jHbOx6T/TCf9s4lIJipb%2BTjU7pw3BOMwRYlYTKJmBMOu1Mp4GXIkxGBJlnoC/so/qMpOxVzwDXOuYpgC6ibk6DcYFqroE5J2byF1AyEXUfHMxgltiSHtGeBMyIIg6MwGWKApdXEQC4LMAiG4CQXKQnOLqBikhgldMpLwtBgaEy9JaAA4qEOQvoZbyK6m2L2tSVz%2B1sQjJZhN9lTJMI2AuGIWV3CoHiQkJIySUhpJiH49JHiAjBBCNk5xoQRlWAkSywACKCOCCkYeBILCEBEIYKkmA6zECUCFBUCBnQJAUCAbko5ionFBMge8WUqBhjQCwTkjA5I9k5KaLBxANycioBEVQG50CNkzOgE4hEEimz1MAYA6pGFRxkWsKMxlC7XAVP9PEwQWZpIxTqPiwodJPg0GBU0HpHgWCELy647czlJi7rLEZ/8IhjgJBfe8atq06n8jPW4c8i6Iu2AASUEBUMCtb%2BJs1jsKYInYjw1kMLUcNvFOwGJoFqnUhx/yt1nfxa4RJHxgSLVSGOup14Bm4dsDc8xdQIHmJi2WShIoWwCAALTcKEPKdMWUaRJTe3WNjA5wwRq2qZ/Ve0uloFqIUqpkBCkbluGaEkFDnoxcDKJTBCQ01hgoCJBJ9yaqUBAVQsws0biieCKDbMdRBklD2tw%2Bl6Zso5cSUkFJqSLWcUzVxidxQEE/P%2B08SqVURPVVhzA8yiwcYSCnBxXG2pOg9iJiTMbaBKCY%2B%2B82n6yxAroI4Bg74swQD/dLWRMbcTRlnsy1dNBlQV0TkeCmuoUT0DRi6cRggmBk3Y3jbYUpgB417FBBhq79zfgwmk7h8VMCqHBEh7FzlbVfnqgmFhnYezk0sYGYMdC5Iob7DDNMjU%2B5bwJAbYco5xyjx1OPSez1j6z1Qtxhel5pxXwulDDeH8oAlbPAfEJlZHE1bPhyBtsEdYkRAZdW%2BP5IHQLaGBYbeY36sRawc6rf1m0cgodY0i02qLgNog/Ri/WvFG36txQMeMJLQdmhJeS1NfbGLbGQ1bJ1nwaBCv1WhUUUOxWYQlVASUawpWxmlLhWVti5QKvgfhpVhUVSqoYWqEip1NSY5JjqCjurFjCZpNRAiRpjSFBNKa%2Bi3NzU3GBCzmPSo7pS%2BR/yObFphVoDk5gjg6wgCzURFB%2BlrE8SIJlxqBiD32ceJaUSOpRBKDAsAPANZyZATkmYSQvMjrxpMSxwJYsOaSzKQEtx4sj5KNQhK7yGh2yaVxZRrgHTot0BXFjcjBjG5sDAg5IwIGzxqfp8ELTmZazRBSAIPdhNr04bnUGJYbaFQbufG4ZQihxKPH3PQSdvOvP403FLDi/1bJChPV4LUMGvzIGxGc8KUH/rk0zYB/tV6CfRyw2kApYJ6JFKqSrEiGv/Tmwk8xhO5jyxs45EN6lwFdOLY5CkZc/8vLoFUASVh32/zKhIpbMfIKCDTCzL3j0GDjcCin50z96%2B0ro%2B2PHhMkv9E%2BnjPUApWu2wea87DPbBtebN5YPtZVU%2BZ%2BJXn8eAsJ19eRnk27icWFjMUn1NhIkHXrVgUbWH1Rh7EeEHWcnDR1AMXNjklNkzVYUwEwAHTaCYHgNDBdw9BvADCRR9CiUu1YmvxV2Bh7zSj3z1hNi336kSSSTcwtVSFEAiikklDAm8kt3oC1VXAcC8GLyrwdGLTXVdwwnd0002EzFXV5H5CzjORXGFx8jQJNmmGen5j1jlwFg4lNj3QgAGS0J0IMO2FUHuXClQCDHFCQzMDkmiwEEYB1ACGwBZQVFN35AsydyuRFBEhIz4K6k8CwH4lr13lxjEhGg6jEIIJ3WoO73cxZHvygJYnvHy3Rmf12jUgOiYN/wZUjEMzjScXfVPAPzZ2em2F8UFgDhhh/WAjvwjTSPfgNlnD0MkE7z6hUU0hdggDaNl2kAEjwIIIDHxkGlKnXF5x9DQH%2BhQLc3oCPHJn0PexkkkhSRRBfUZRM3jQN3ZUwHxDLGuHJAAA0CwuAzByQAgyxW4y1kAK0U1ssdRct4IhwmAaxVBzjgJ94LxvcZwmxUIFRFBHhuxvMEAvAqAqBbJnJ9xhEqp5dfsXZvxnIDEXDAxHgpiCASdRoVJyZuckNqdO08opRQM1QhRQ5UAKldQuDHhMB65aAoMfQvj0tCA/jroFAwIxitRgYc5gY0SbQYMXQnJElWcvQUM5ICIGA8AEgMVT8/cLNDBKSTthRohw0JSdIWZYMISoSgCFRlB7wIhMYGTtx9w9wDwrNo4ohnRohV0/Cs0C0R02Bxp8Q2BiA1T/JNTwTITbIwJVRyYkMlB4k4sz1tS7MLMZouoawqJ0BvwmAix5cNwQQjdGULAPQuBtiwJEyWAeJOwAwSMNUbSZZ95/J%2BZtgSl7sX5LphICBNMH54zywdIQJJs/iUYFQeI8zohBcGAZSdRo4YIwJ4CqAMUpDXSJdxQD1XQwQfQmj%2BJ3pXCZEetfiax5CGs15v06zJAmz/i9NTxlysxVy3j0B0BIF4yQJ5Cptr5LooITzJBVAIBc1th4ywILj6JnyABOMwBbbfFJazBgPofiEU1Y7nPnA4nUEUuk6ybYOcm2BBTSWEkRVcdAbQEaVw9YvALVXqYACecc0C1cMrVSVcUUs9bEbOWwgdHRf3Ega9AwHJWURaPcr3IbS8hs2if6KST0deG8s8rMMCcsnST6c82seQ1szSOcI8qC3aec3mf6IJIwFmbySg%2B8HyPioiHNFUt0x4fyFEPDCoa9fcBIAwKqMjEMPnWw10aC12PlQ3VGEIYMV0EUmaa9JQFWYAfcBMci4aU7ZSOcBcNIIUbtJheKfUSnc4GWFS4iBZEicKxEQEbiI/IgJyDLEiHM5MLcbyG3EMO/CSkcKSsYiSfso9MYt5JPR4fnWYmCpxBig8y6fyVpeqaIRweM1QJ%2BQS8KgSniys98VyPLFIF87izMPDKFI/CyJOUXeY0q2w9zMQKgFOVUzAdUtnAxLKiyv5GUVyeyrqO9RgH5KIyMr8YgFgb8TKT7P3CvWgWnM05HLqabULcLBwLihisCO2I/FIWgY0gQn3T6cFZEizKM7GY8GWKqpixrcFYgB6wSx6yKepOcddU4%2BhX7aIQ6jyqIggF3HiZADcTYDEqi0quLX4LcP3LarqTo4lKTFHG6sLSye6h%2BBGSGp7XqBUP6msAGpxcJAwcUQ4Ogbg3BYETZNQkk5yOsSmmIl8rkZKW6lZY7M5EMUETzHUKJVAL0Qm7a%2BXIFXsoUAPR4U6vtWgLYgAhTWC6zcqxhOoR4BQAiN6sqTAcNIQ9QmgXsrqN7GKC6q9PEtze3TS5BYytLDLCymzZcSSHRQI8/JyKSdC1cca70YUtgiaw9dmoA08aKycKKligKS4aEOKnctsJOtbcKo/C1JgUTXGaOCWgk5BecXUFFeTazA4mgAvRgDG5Goq3k6zYIATIizNUc8mKcwi/nFal2qNcReDYYjMLRQ04GbybwqvPkmJD0KiB5PhbYXFZQXdWDEijk3CSk7YD0Ne61CwswU2Oe7GU%2BF86sfnYGyiCBUu9oICVQSQSBBGabManqvAPqhivDNqoSjqoarOjkd9c6P8YW6mgCBGA9MCT8%2BKtzRSmY%2BYRqVY02iO6zG3IgJKBytzLK78OlP5Yk6OTmy2tAQ4IUehLwecDe/NWaEM70wVQWaMv5CwCiwgF3OOYIZ2QwM2r0nUiVWNF2gsrqTWknXm8UTNAkuasqH0AxZB77bYTBlSKWuza%2BjTYAC6oG6xabNikaD0KUcGjq9%2Bhm8ye8I8MakKy0F8lk54th2Oa1V0dRji1AC67kFRyGZi2q/algYFafDc/q3i1O9qzMKbIkIkAkIQAACTkBlBlHcJMNIHiFzSexEuuXiijhwrslrrOTwFcIZIupzufAgBzvTuwChoFiLGUtTqeHye6mhv5ySs5wFEhOSM824gGQyxFOCB7KmuDtHqWPFBQz%2BQ6S9EAXlXBEqiqDAkNB1CN07ALERQZLAlzJxvEU/CtyEKPprERXP2pLEHZkzTRN3vlooqzgEiVJfWoWybIjzt/rMn3lPsTkPQvoHivqAcatvL/k8afu6teKvNfsdn6o/p8a/r8e4mhtHPmoGcEHEYWMmpkaJguvfQPTfw0GOgZSZR%2BkjgFsFA%2BVcrpLcjsuICeJ51Qw%2BbhQ%2BK%2BIJBrG%2BNqxbIBNPhLK0mquwmaI3NTq3M%2BnrD0aOw7IklaYYaFGgYHKUCHIik7tVPJhnLEZufMsksEAXLbB%2BKen%2Bbpb7k8a%2Bk70cc6pSW0YBem2vI3LvIfKfMadfO4g/K/Je3EoMT/OKHsvxCAvBdKtwvApGhDAstIUaiVlg34hIjwg%2BGhHTIudVY2wgRsc0bwA1dWRKXdd8d8fiagrrC6gsqsWfFFZ1m8lZPXB5YEAUkvh2Wp0Ch4mBdFO0rAl0seALX/GswnNnMlcsqcTdYQA9dQWsS9cOQVA9ArhZ3RsxrsxooboJq6jGe2ARZllrY9fFVHefDMCPx3qlGtRiB2oxqxpchdHxq7X7amYgDOumD%2BSJp2uji4HuO7eXb93oTGelY5CucdjPsmruZqoebuscFvvvppu%2BOYufsJd6u%2BffrDbzDrcjcBc73/pBHfBrF0RfLglAdsMcW2JRc0jtIiUc0OClQrslHvC8AaajUyh9CKrg%2BsjaC9AMTTXpxCommP3%2BilPFFZMnowCxkI4Ak9BHXkmOJOLki%2BKTAaiWDxerLqMEEQhQRHzMlhe/Ty3eM%2BIuNJefca21YAiaogG6O4lICGK4DkACACEBEBCLFiearif/bJq6heLfGE5JbJdLGYqgnfi3kQkg%2BRd2M7QACkewM1OwhyGA%2BXHhftos0kFBgZudXLMZrMF1exoHsq2AKqFQcHcdUrAwSAd6pDws6ByYYIN6DnFjXhQAKZ9wXcbwGE2ZPRnJBRPBgyDFmlZmIuAghAOIohRACCUk24vAIhJJ7wpJgBgzRBiA3UUSFjQLV0AB1EgcjaLOoMvOdOt%2BYTzNpizA9jGrtM6he7doYmsBQe0Q4HcM09eI8T4O4h41MHuXnQTwlgzi4h6M%2BZVqralnSfmCs6bTjp9pl5%2BZVi52Vxedij0etRi1R5xnSEpdz3BB%2Boffiyli58pXidCw4F7ulhRn7iAJ7l7sCem5tzSecRcPmkSH0Jmlm9CZbfyKKEiChPSHyOSRT1T/YRseJxDuEx4SsXmRsZ6LHwWKKYRrqcKTNpS6ca6Y7TsiUQOagYHh/Aas2MwY5no3WAn/YQERsIHxhS0GggUEEeiP5Lr1LX1jnNwRsR3b7ACQQjW9nrC8mP8yNN1PEn0BH3m5cRHOnBnU/ZnWpnyHNh7J7Y/HT1HIsbTq6wkaCeouxfznn%2B2WnswZ6bCb9OxTHiBvTVdMQc3pndgfDQjQOXmKCSFD86wIsVYZ8x2RP5Px8zoywJPsCJP9ozqxVhIU8%2BrScXWY7hNTSbzp0DnrLQKJPwZGGfo%2BTPALchFcMvGLqVoBwazCEOWzehgJnn0Z11YOUIkkjF3AU1ztoVn0hpuqL8L8tmPrAJyIJS0S0IMt6ioEKo2tXjzyhzhztNznf3BKo6OYhmfhe%2Bdbn6ZzObAgigxQBQiJMHs1ZLegxFnzsKIBuDh%2BgANVddQ9FS9EbyXDxZ%2BIE3LcGrU3rzEUOo3HRH8mwAKB88eAMQpmmZIZZ3%2BQhbWkBlXRsxcQKYK5MkjeoD8n%2BFFUXJpRSLZxb%2BhFLBL8AQBbErOrKLEPsUOIEhGOXxckBYCJDdo/4BIVdDCgoJb0rStFZRDgPQB4DqoS0WgEQPqzRwxYYRUPsqD4HjF1QHyAiAWllhORM0n/ewhEDszc4CC7hFlBt07iPFtuKBXbvp2JYXEawEQUEOSyO6ssTuB/BIF91FB1dvaTsX2lW1jhvVbCQoAwTFzcxmYxA1fRqP6C9hu83gPaVGhwCFCglhoQoKgK5FiTJQXBnnKbjrQXoR4UauofUP21pinciIUUC7sxSu4MQbuzZO7nxwe7VgoeeEOlv5E%2B5H9RQ42HTH90qH14tooyIHoulB7XtAGd7CHrUIBaw9TIuqFItsCa7EBDSM6VUMoIET4BDgCwOrhEKDhAR7QOUfiB2SRQQtD0T%2BaOA%2BVoTJYEGg7L4OsHxDpkZYd2bNIFBzTPZE0DAPiB1EZwVBYcizDXuIQ9C9cI0rHF0FZhFLrhUgQjTsCs2BgEcUCPoAggRAtSoA5IQ5JQF5wjSchtAo0RHH/Qd564uGgBRaDjw5w5NheSvc2CTyEQIVzY5hf0CsK549C8Is4enhIKkFT8SAi0T3r0IbbPh8ecgQnm4COhw97I%2BCJyGCOciy8OQHgYemzBxhsxiYTQoUMCwWo4owWhFdAWsUMhcANAEzXJN9idBSgjAyNdQryRHSKiqIXDYom7Ad7%2B93eCMZkdSIsJewzRuYQPuJhD70CDM%2BAEos6O8j9RWBFxK4ii2eiroDm8BANByByhdQzqYEYdKuCxgUUpm87LtnjUbpR8zay0PVMaUEGuhRIHfa6LuHjxJxV0EAsSAYgIZgV8QHSa4AEEJQkMDUL6QHsxXB7XdJ0YNYIFPkO5Llmy6YasG2hTJtgT6F7JMLvmBpAddEWEd9oxDwDdYZWFLSdBFDpauNgU9Y%2BiKoCwhPtmWnVV9qB3M6NjcMY4tES71k4ANkAwHYcWB3E5vhX2b4YcSBDEALZ84nwZ6KJX7zxoFQPmVYrPiShG5gq3OBAW0ELwswcgqQAQOt1qAdxkwKadrL8RQyp0iWzVKGAoAiD%2BIpe6YBgM9lk6ngASyE%2B8U4mqFrMhQfUPoVBC4AQ98eW40CXKxzCHAsIFPXCU6Ah6VhSAZgOXNEw/LRN1OKfV8m%2BSLCkAny60BlEWQpa7McJb3CTk6HwlLjEJW%2BVEa1D4mtRcJtXBQHRC8BcASwpE%2BWH/Bom7MjYp8JcnSzHC0AawEPFwhyTUmd4HG8LY6LzARYXNjJB0dMr/l5g1g38E7GyQZCPzZcPQUGCNIN34grCTRLvOyY6J2KlpAJ5aYwVt2uDpgpUYISCX/Dxh3lMJWZDsR2icTrxxQIBVjOmFUBv5OiBRC5txhM6ZjN4HzKANUNehWE4pXRNsOFMEBUB5kE7QsBoAUm0ATiAsAsHVKLANSmpLUtqeYGan1TGp/eOiWBHSkHRVgx0UgINIsAOSt0Y06yZNJMm/4iJ76cyfridHxp0wBEYIIhCpY/wb8bYzvJhPSkh8ZYmaCAHgBpwoQTp%2BwQsI2BMgnTLA1gBsAlNk4VSCAVU8wAfV5ivSiJp4cAtYnAm1VhOf8eTLBNHFlSOQT0yKQSGik4ZPp5UkVM9Oqn7Q3AyYTnrhnemFg1g4BAsIjNel5pzBA8EcEPCEybjO8UHGWE9Jel0SEZDAD6dxKcTfSnGgk2GEuNiakBmZA7aJgWGiYsyiJZM6qXTIFjB8LAYM/6RDNCxQyTIPM16ZTL6IoySIXU6sJTOxn4sWsRMi5nzK1ZUSmZLMrWYa2Zm5ousneCWXRL5nUyUIQsj4lFNFm4ZxZsM8mQ5MRnSy%2Bkz4OWbsExlUz%2BpSs8zirL45qyTOGskBsBA04qjmZOshiWYC1kjDFohst6bLLonsQzZUEyGVbNNk2z4Zrsh2ajILDyzXZisvTsWChlESfZDMgiTE1UBBztZMPLWUBC5kGyU5r042bHOtkRThZicuObXIplpzkZjspqVnKxnuzc5JYL2T9G8kexFp%2BcDgLMFoCcACwvAPwBwC0CkBUAnAfSLdMFhZQFgVUNYDwFIAEBNA482YB6BACOwTgBYN8m%2BQ0BAQT59ESQKsFWAFhGwr5SeRwEkAzzd5C8zgLwENS5od5c88eaQDgCwAkAH1MgBQB3hvD%2BgwAc3GHJoD04fclACIK/JpjMA3UnALeYgrqAbgcoEQbQFPxQW8BbUwXAgMGIZKvysAQKYAG4HCiGpuAvALAJKWADiAf5pAfAPuHaB1gqF880LG0GBSvzUUj8%2BeS6kshuoPAWAV%2BciBYC4LZgUJJgMAAUDkh0mAYHKDFlwUyBBAqqcQFIBUXyAlAagV%2BboGkDs1jAfoSwPoDwC1p4AswI3rvE4DoF7ickHKB0nVKLAxUj4VQPRCLByR4yckGsA4q67hReAYCVrnokNSQBZgnfKoC4FxAjBmgpAQICmkmD9B4gv4qoFEuyDJA/xDACYP%2BT0BhKOgQwBoJ4CaDZL3I7QAQJ0HqCZLLWMQMYMMAKWjBbAeSipVMChRzB157AZpY/OnmkBZ588xeRwEsJuKPF8uYAKNG4irATg9CCALgEICdhN50wXgN/K0BIRSAeMI8P0EQikAD5cuE4I2AuLm5zYXABSUBEbDFh9AnAZ%2BaQHEVlzul/i9%2BbYBABfzd5swf%2BYgBQBq8lm5ASgEApQAGKuAjYOqXwHUywL%2BiCC4IOguUVoK3UmC7BQ4GUX4LXCRCjcCQswBkKKFb1KhVvNoWGB6Fyweecwqn5n52FvAThcgG4WMLeFr8gReguEU4r5lEIcRdQskUGAZFcizAAoqUXULNFaitpdIH4CCBgSOixhboGT4GKUARimwC6mCXrLLF9UaxaoFsX2LdYBEJxU%2BGHRjFLackXxeqq643hHUf5eEbCJkpVB/FmqCEFgElWhLil4SrWJEtqXRLYlhQLJYkrSXJLbVqS3IGkEaUJLyglQXJV0BSUtBLVvq8pXEsdX1K/Vrq6pd0BDWVKJAoS%2BYIsDaUTyp5L8xhb0v6XuL4yvIrFdxEbAnANAJwHiJMvwCs9Zl8yx5bMBWVhFKA%2B8w%2BWMr%2BX0R6IxyxsEn0bBxA6pwqs5bwEuWqiulr83pR/PuXbzHlf8mAFAFHUQAkAE0Z/iAqAWhBmEnAVxRmqGUjLzc4yolcWpIBFQ9AvK4QDSQkA8rZA/K9QIKtiCkAAwlkBIBItOUcBOl1yt%2BRwByg6I2mIpRdYMomErqxlEyjwGAo9bfBJAcyodT/KWWbLfkxYDQDsvNiSB6IGgNxasBV6Pzzl4igsPzyLBmBwN6nAsKsEkCSAzAbE3tamtuWfzANiykdfAAnWvKf1Hy0Ber36DLkDQpLLgG%2BQJCrBG8qgJ8tApySGpgVjCiFYio5W8aoVOCjlXCsEAIqkVKKyhcosxVGAGFuK9CvirYWvziVpKreeSsYWUqhFtoURXSqvVSLmV8ixRYwGUU7quV%2B6zRUet0WHz9AWK0VSvPFWmLzVC83ylYo4B2L6EtcJxSAEY5mBjV0QU1eqHMXer8Vzga1e4AjUxLcQnqqpYkGdVpB/VMW91fkGjVNKgtJS6oHkvi05LSlDS5LV6svz5LMg0S/LVFtjUtKE1pWjpSmp6WcBLCma0cMuVrCMaTgLGnyFMpLXfAoUZaoDRWrpJVr1lCGrtbEFzVwaPyqwN8pICLAFg75GgaQHev7V3KHl3WjZYfP55vlGwp8gsPRGQ1FhGNCyO%2BdetWBVablHALrYsqTUcAfN%2BG6rSduI17zSAERPwJICAA%3D), we get asm like this to count `ymm0` into `esi` (inlined into `main`'s loop.)

```
# GCC13.2 -O3 -march=x86-64-v3     (or -march=haswell)
# lzcnt_si256_memsrc inside a loop in main, after printf
   vmovdqa ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rsp]
   vpxor   xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
   mov     esi, 256
   vpcmpeqd        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1  # could have used a memory source operand
   vpmovmskb       eax, ymm0
   xor     eax, -1                   # ~mask and set FLAGS, unlike the NOT instruction
   je      .L33
   xor     ecx, ecx            # dep-breaking for lzcnt
   mov     edx, 28
   lzcnt   ecx, eax
   sub     rdx, rcx
   lzcnt   edx, DWORD PTR [rsp+32+rdx]  # Un-laminates into 2 uops with an indexed addr mode.  mov rdx, rsp ; sub would have allowed [rdx+32+28] here
   lea     esi, [rdx+rcx*8]          # lzbytes*8 + lzcnt(nz chunk)
.L33:   # jump target for mask==0
```

Clang likes to do `vptest  ymm0, ymm0` / `jne` for the early-out, costing more uops than just waiting to test the movemask result.  Perhaps an `[[unlikely]]` annotation or non-portable equivalent could help.

GCC's non-inline version is better in some ways (`sub` against the pointer arg and +28 as part of the addr mode for `lzcnt edx, [rdi+28]` which can [stay micro-fused on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes) since it only uses one reg.) But GCC wastes a `mov` reg copy and two dep-breaking xor-zeroing instructions even though both `lzcnt` instructions can overwrite their inputs (or a reg holding a pointer for the mem-src version).  Sometimes it's possible to rearrange your C in ways that help, but it depends on the surrounding code where this inlines.

---

**[`bsr`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/BSR) instead of `31 - lzcnt`** on the mask could reduce critical path latency on Intel: no SUB or NEG, just adding something as part of the addressing mode for the scalar load.  GCC8 and earlier would emit it for `31-__builtin_clz()`, but current GCC just uses `31-lzcnt` or `31^lzcnt` even with `-march=haswell` where both have identical performance characteristics (including the output dependency.)

If you're tuning specifically for Intel, BSR might still be a good idea.  But for portable software, BSR is significantly slower on AMD than LZCNT, which is relevant everywhere except x86-64 macOS.  But good luck getting compilers other than MSVC to emit it.

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#include <stdalign.h>  //MSVC is missing this?
#else
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_BitScanReverse)  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd.aspx suggests this
#endif

// undefined result for mask=0, like BSR
static inline uint32_t bsr_nonzero(uint32_t mask)
{
// on Intel, bsr has a minor advantage for the first step
// for AMD, BSR is slow so you should use 31-LZCNT.

 // Intel's docs say there should be a _bit_scan_reverse(x), maybe try that with ICC
 #ifdef _MSC_VER
    unsigned long tmp;
    _BitScanReverse(&tmp, mask);
    return tmp;
 #else
    return 31 - __builtin_clz(mask);  // GCC 9 and later use lzcnt even with -march=haswell implying tune for Intel, leading to worse code.  Same for clang
 #endif
}
```

[In C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/countr_zero) there's `31 - std::countr_zero(mask)` - all CPUs with AVX2 also have BMI1/BMI2, so compilers will be able to use `lzcnt` for it.  There's no portable C equivalent.  (On CPUs without BMI1, `countr_zero` would be slightly slower because it guarantees `32` for mask=0, unlike the `bsr` instruction or intrinsic, or GNU `__builtin_clz`.  So it would branch or CMOV on the input being zero.)

##### BSR version using byte elements

Not recommended in general, but I didn't want to throw this away.  It compiles with a BSR on MSVC **but is worse with GCC and Clang**.  Change the `#if` to `1` for `lzcnt`, for a byte-source version for unaligned data to avoid cache-line and page splits on the scalar load (but not the vec).

```
int lzcnt_si256_byte_memsrc(const void *m256)
{
    __m256i  vec = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)m256);
    __m256i   nonzero_elem = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(vec, _mm256_setzero_si256());
    uint32_t  mask = ~_mm256_movemask_epi8(nonzero_elem);   //  1 where there are non-zero bytes

    // alternative: mask |= 1 to lzcnt the low byte in that case, giving 32-24 = 8
    if (mask == 0)
        return 256;
    unsigned char *elems = (unsigned char*)m256;

#if 0  // GCC13 compiles both the same, clang's __builtin_clz version is worse (xor twice)
// Unless you're specifically tuning for Intel, use this version
    uint8_t *end_elem = elems + 31;
    unsigned   lz_msk   = _lzcnt_u32(mask);
    size_t   idx_from_end = -(size_t)lz_msk;    // idx = 31 - lz_msk;  // relative to start
    unsigned   highest_nonzero_byte = end_elem[idx_from_end];
#else
    unsigned   idx = bsr_nonzero(mask);   // use bsr to get the 31-x for free, because it's known to be non-zero
    unsigned   lz_msk = 31 - idx;    // off the critical path, if compilers actually use BSR
// MSVC notices that (31-idx)*8 - 24 + x  is (28-idx)*8 + x,  allowing a 2-component LEA
// GCC and clang miss that, in older versions that actually use BSR
    unsigned   highest_nonzero_byte = elems[idx];
#endif
    return     lz_msk * 8 + _lzcnt_u32(highest_nonzero_byte) - 24;
    // lzcnt(byte)-24, because we don't want to count the leading 24 bits of padding.
}
```

On AMD CPUs, `bsr` is significantly slower than `lzcnt`.  On Intel CPUs, they're the same performance, except for minor variations in [output-dependency details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter).  (`lzcnt` has a false dependency before Skylake. `bsr` has a *true* dependency on the output for all CPUs.)

`bsr` with input=0 leaves the destination register unmodified, but intrinsics don't provide a way to take advantage of that to get CMOV-like behaviour for free.  (Intel only documents it as undefined output, but AMD documents the actual behaviour of Intel / AMD CPUs as producing the old value in the destination register).

`bsr` sets ZF if the *input* was zero, rather than based on the output like most instructions.  (This and the output dependency may be why it's slow on AMD.)  Branching on the BSR flags is not particularly better than branching on ZF as set by `xor eax,-1` to invert the mask, which is what gcc does.  Anyway, Intel does [document a `_BitScanReverse(&idx, mask)` intrinsic](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1825,5214,433,720,4251,4464,4464,719,4567,4638,4637,4637,1724,396&text=bsr) that returns a `bool`, but gcc doesn't support it (not even with `x86intrin.h`).  The GNU C builtin doesn't return a boolean to let you use the flag result, and doesn't normally use the FLAGS result even when you check the input C variable for non-zero.

---

Wim's version needs `lz_msk-24` because the high 24 bits are always zero with an 8-bit mask.  But a 32-bit mask fills a 32-bit reg.

This version with 8 bit elements and a 32-bit mask is the reverse: we need to `lzcnt` the selected byte, *not* including the 24 leading zero bits in the register.  So our `-24` moves to a different spot, not part of the critical path for indexing the array.

GCC chooses to do it as part of a single 3-component LEA  (`reg + reg*scale - const`), which is great for throughput, but puts it on the critical path after the final `lzcnt`.  (3-component LEA has extra latency vs. `reg + reg*scale` on Intel before Ice Lake.  See [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/), and https://uops.info/ for testing of different LEA addr modes on Ice Lake and Alder Lake; any scaled index is now a slow-LEA, but still 1c latency until Alder, and more ports.)

Clang with some `-march` options makes a mess, favouring latency over throughput by using more instructions instead of a complex LEA.  But sometimes it breaks things up more than necessary.

A multiply by 8 can be done as part of an `lea`, but a multiply by 32 would need a shift (or be folded into two separate LEAs).

---

[Intel's optimization manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) says (Table 2-24) even Sandybridge can forward from a 256-bit store to single-byte loads without a problem, so I think it's fine on AVX2 CPUs, the same as forwarding to 32-bit loads that of 4-byte-aligned chunks of the store.

---

#### AVX-512 versions, maybe not faster, just an experiment

Store/reload might still be a better strategy, especially with data already in memory to avoid the store part.  We can make the low element special, always true or always false, with `vptestnmb` against a vector of all-ones except the low dword, getting the `nz |= 0xf` for free.

AVX-512 has `vplzcntq` to do per-element 64-bit bit-scan.  Doing that before a store could shorten critical-path latency by overlapping the lzcnt with the element-index calculation.  But it takes a vector ALU instead of the port-1 ALU on Intel CPUs which can't run 512-bit vector uops (or any vector uops when there are any 512-bit uops in flight.)

The fun way is to shuffle and blend using the mask to pick one of four elements,  I was hoping I could use `vpcompressq` to left-pack, but that gets lowest not highest.  A horizontal-sum type of shuffle + blend pattern can grab the lower element only if the high element's mask bit was zero.  Shuffles themselves can use merge-masking, including into the same reg for single-uop reduction steps.  But the mask instructions to prepare the mask aren't fast.

```
// See Godbolt for the first 2 attempts at this

// this isn't great either
int lzcnt_si256_avx512_v2(__m256i vec)
{
    __mmask8 nz = _mm256_test_epi64_mask(vec, vec); // 1 where input is non-zero, useful for merging higher into lower elements
    __m256i vclz = _mm256_lzcnt_epi64(vec);
    vclz = _mm256_add_epi64(vclz, _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 64, 128, 192));  // add the number of bits to the left of each element
    int nz_shr = nz>>1;
    vclz = _mm256_mask_unpackhi_epi64(vclz, nz_shr, vclz, vclz); //  even elements = higher elem if it was non-zero (nz_mask=1 merge masking), else keep the lower element
    nz_shr |= nz;  // kand: 1 cycle latency on port 0
    nz_shr >>= 2;  // kshiftr: 4 cycle latency on port 5 (Intel).  Zen 4 is 1c latency on 2 ports
    __m128i low = _mm256_mask_extracti32x4_epi32(_mm256_castsi256_si128(vclz), nz_shr, vclz, 1);
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(low);
}
```

#### Trailing zero count via `vpcompressd` to left-pack based on non-zero mask

```
// Just for fun, use vpcompressd to grab the first non-zero element
// Worth comparing for throughput and latency on Intel and Zen 4, vs. store/reload
static inline
int tzcnt_si256_avx512(__m256i vec)
{
    __mmask8 mask = _mm256_test_epi32_mask(vec, vec);
    __m256i pack_nz = _mm256_maskz_compress_epi32(mask, vec);
    uint32_t first_nz = _mm256_extract_epi32(pack_nz, 0);  // optimizes to vmovd
    uint32_t mask32 = mask | (-1U<<7); // produce 256 = 7*32 + 32 for an all-zero vector where tzcnt(first_nz) = 32.
      // -1U<<7 fits in signed imm8.  With 1<<7, compilers were going nuts trying to optimize
      // alternative: if (mask==0) return 256;
    return _tzcnt_u32(first_nz) + 32*_tzcnt_u32(mask32);
}
```

On Godbolt I included a version that uses VBMI2 (Ice Lake) `vpcompressb` so the final `x + 32*y` can be `*8` instead, allowing LEA.  But that makes it harder to handle an all-zero mask; see the code comments on Godbolt.

Another tzcnt strategy could involve `vplzcntq( v & -v )`, and subtracting that from a vector of `set_epi64x(192+63, 128+63, 64+63, 63)` to get tzcnt=63-lzcnt(blsi(vec)).  Then select the right non-zero element?  That's more vector ops, but runs the lzcnt dep chain in parallel with the compress shuffle.  `vpcompress*` is 2 uops, and the first only needs the mask as input, not the vector being shuffled.  (Presumably it processes a mask into a shuffle-control for vperm*).  That would optimize for latency but not throughput.  More vector uops is even more of a downside if using 512-bit vectors.

Handling the all-zero input case might need a branch with the compress strategy, unless we wanted to do a merge-masked `sub` into a vector of `set1(256)`.  63-lzcnt only works for lzcnt in [0..63]; it would need `-1` instead of `64` to get the result we want for the input=0 case.  That wouldn't hurt instruction-level parallelism badly: the `vplzcntq` could still run in parallel with with the compare-into-mask, and `vpsubq` would have to wait for both to be ready.  And that's also separate from the compress reading the mask from the compare.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the in-depth explanation.
The movemask approach looks quite elegant.
However, for some reason I could not figure out yet, the function "mm256_lzcnt_si256" you proposed does not compute the same indices as the code I listed.

Comment: @SvenHager: Thanks, I spotted (and fixed) a bug: lzcnt_u32 of a zero-extended byte needs a `-24`.  Was that the only bug?  I didn't test it myself, since I was sure the main logic was correct, and was mostly thinking about performance issues.  Correctness is just a matter of debugging and minor changes :P

Comment: Hmm, still an issue there ...
However, it must be a minor thing, as the indices computed by your code are close to that computed by mine.
I will post my test program above.

Comment: I posted my eval code in the question.
Sorry that it's a bit lengthy, as it also contains the corresponding functions for 64 and 128 bits.

Comment: @SvenHager: I don't have time to look at it right now; I'll get back to this later today and debug my answer, if you or someone else doesn't spot the remaining bug before then.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your support. =)

Comment: @SvenHager I think the bug resides in your code. I spotted yesterday that you extract 64-bit integers in the wrong order - according to lzcnt "offsets" that you use (0, 64, 128, 192) the order should be (3,2,1,0) and not the opposite.

Comment: When I correct the extraction order in @SvenHager method, both of my functions and also the function by PeterCordes return the same results. Btw, if you are interested, I added some benchmark data to my response, check it out. And thanks for all the advice.

Comment: @PeterCordes We can eliminate movzx by _mm256_cmpeq_epi32 and taking lzcnt of (unsigned&)elems[idx-3]. This index is correct, because all the other bits will be zero in mask. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9PGM85r8q

Comment: @PeterMudrievskij: That has strict-aliasing and alignment UB.  You need `memcpy` to do an unaligned `uint32_t` load.  But yes, good idea since GCC's going to spend the instructions to align `uint8_t tmp[32]` anyway, and store-forwarding from an aligned vector to an unaligned dword load is efficient on all AVX2 CPUs, I think.  (https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/).  I'll edit when I have time.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, so that's why I get random wrong results when not using memcpy (https://godbolt.org/z/xfM1sh11n). Thank you

Comment: @PeterMudrievskij: Yeah.  I updated my answer with an lzcnt version that loads an aligned dword; I had the same idea of using `cmpeq_epi32` (I hadn't noticed your version was doing that; I had assumed it was buggy and would read past the end of the array if the significant bit was in one of the highest 3 bytes.)  With lzcnt hitting the top of a 4-bit group from a non-zero dword, it offsets things by 3.  But with `char*` math we can compenate, and casting back to an aligned `uint32_t*` for deref, everything is strict-aliasing safe.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually `memcpy` is still needed in the first function to avoid strict-aliasing UB (https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8). `uint32_t*` accessing `unsigned char*` data is UB (the reverse is ok). Just to be sure I ran it through `tis-interpreter`: `warning: The pointer nz_elem has type unsigned int *. It violates strict aliasing rules by accessing a cell with effective type char *`

Comment: @PeterCordes Also we don't need to store the vector. Casting to `char*` is safe `(char*)&vec`. GCC can decide if store is needed. 
`memcpy(&nz_dword, (char*)&vec + (28 - lzbytes), sizeof(nz_dword));`

Comment: @PeterMudrievskij: I'm pretty sure your sanitizer is wrong.  The underlying data is a `uint32_t elems[8]` array.  We do some pointer math using `char*` before casting back to a valid aligned `uint32_t*` that points to a `uint32_t` object within the same array object the `char*` was derived from.  I *think* all of this is well-defined even in strict ISO C, and I'm fairly sure it is in GNU C.  (I did apparently miss updating the version in the answer from the Godbolt version, and had only elems[4], though, so I'm glad you commented).

Comment: @PeterMudrievskij: See [Does casting to a char pointer to increment a pointer by a certain amount and then accessing as a different type violate strict aliasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71861366) - round-trip through `char*` to do some pointer math is safe, as long as the `int*` you actually dereference is pointing to an `int` object.  (As long as you follow the other rules, like not deriving a pointer outside the original array object.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Looks like you are right, as always (nice profile pic :P). What about casting vector directly to `char*` instead of `storeu`? In this case both GCC and Clang can optimize away the redundant store and we can get rid of `…_memsrc`.

Comment: @PeterMudrievskij: That would work, but then I'd need `memcpy`; I felt it was cleaner not to use it.  I did leave a comment in the code that we could define `int lzcnt_si256(__m256i vec){ return lzcnt_si256_memsrc(&vec);  }`; GCC and Clang do optimize away the `&` in the caller / `_mm256_loadu_si256` in callee, but I didn't want to tempt compilers into doing an extra copy.  Maybe some codebases will want to refactor it if they actually want both versions for different use-cases.

Answer (score 4):

(Update: new answer since 2019-01-31)

Three alternatives are:

- [Peter Cordes' excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49217087). Fast. 
  This solution is not branchless, which should not be a problem, unless the input 
  is frequently zero with an irregular pattern of occurrences.
- My previous answer which is in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49215284/3) of this answer now. Less efficient 
  than Peter Cordes' answer, but branchless.
- This answer. Very fast if the data from the 2 tiny lookup tables is in L1 cache.
  The L1 cache footprint is 128 bytes. Branchless. It may suffer from cache misses 
  when called not often.

In this answer, the input `epi64` vector is compared with zero, which produces a mask. 
This mask is converted to a 4-bit index `i_mask` (by `_mm256_movemask_pd`).
With index `i_mask` two values are read from the two lookup tables:
1. the index of the first nonzero 64-bit element, and 2.
the number of nonzeros of the preceding (from left to right) zero elements.
Finally, the `_lzcnt_u64` of the first nonzero 64-bit element is computed and added 
to the lookup table value. Function `mm256_lzcnt_si256` implements this method:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
/* gcc -Wall -m64 -O3 -march=haswell clz_avx256_upd.c */


int mm256_lzcnt_si256(__m256i input)
{   
    /* Version with lookup tables and scratch array included in the function                                                                  */

    /* Two tiny lookup tables (64 bytes each, less space is possible with uint8_t or uint16_t arrays instead of uint32_t):                       */
    /* i_mask  (input==0)                 0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111                        */
    /* ~i_mask (input!=0)                 1111 1110 1101 1100 1011 1010 1001 1000 0111 0110 0101 0100 0011 0010 0001 0000                        */
    static const uint32_t indx[16]   = {   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   2,   2,   2,   2,   1,   1,   0,   0};
    static const uint32_t lz_msk[16] = {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  64,  64,  64,  64, 128, 128, 192, 192};

    alignas(32)  uint64_t tmp[4]     = {   0,   0,   0,   0};                /* tmp is a scratch array of 32 bytes, preferably 32 byte aligned   */ 

                          _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&tmp[0], input);     /* Store input in the scratch array                                 */
    __m256i  mask       = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(input, _mm256_setzero_si256()); /* Check which 64 bits elements are zero                            */
    uint32_t i_mask     = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_castsi256_pd(mask));     /* Move vector mask to integer mask                                 */
    uint64_t input_i    = tmp[indx[i_mask]];                                 /* Load the first (from the left) non-zero 64 bit element input_i   */
    int32_t  lz_input_i = _lzcnt_u64(input_i);                               /* Count the number of leading zeros in input_i                     */
    int32_t  lz         = lz_msk[i_mask] + lz_input_i;                       /* Add the number of leading zeros of the preceding 64 bit elements */
             return lz;
}    


int mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(__m256i input, uint64_t* restrict tmp, const uint32_t* indx, const uint32_t* lz_msk)
{   
    /* Version that compiles to nice assembly, although, after inlining there won't be any difference between the different versions.            */
                          _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)&tmp[0], input);     /* Store input in the scratch array                                 */
    __m256i  mask       = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(input, _mm256_setzero_si256()); /* Check which 64 bits elements are zero                            */
    uint32_t i_mask     = _mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_castsi256_pd(mask));     /* Move vector mask to integer mask                                 */
    uint64_t input_i    = tmp[indx[i_mask]];                                 /* Load the first (from the left) non-zero 64 bit element input_i   */
    int32_t  lz_input_i = _lzcnt_u64(input_i);                               /* Count the number of leading zeros in input_i                     */
    int32_t  lz         = lz_msk[i_mask] + lz_input_i;                       /* Add the number of leading zeros of the preceding 64 bit elements */
             return lz;
}    


__m256i bit_mask_avx2_lsb(unsigned int n)               
{           
    __m256i ones       = _mm256_set1_epi32(-1);
    __m256i cnst32_256 = _mm256_set_epi32(256,224,192,160, 128,96,64,32);
    __m256i shift      = _mm256_set1_epi32(n);   
            shift      = _mm256_subs_epu16(cnst32_256,shift);  
                  return _mm256_srlv_epi32(ones,shift);
}


int print_avx2_hex(__m256i ymm)
{
    long unsigned int x[4];
        _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)x,ymm);
        printf("%016lX %016lX %016lX %016lX  ", x[3],x[2],x[1],x[0]);
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    __m256i x;

    printf("mm256_lzcnt_si256\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 257; i++){
        printf("x=");
        x = bit_mask_avx2_lsb(i);
        print_avx2_hex(x);
        printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256(x));
    }
    printf("\n");

    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,0, 0,15,1,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256(x));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,8, 0,0,0,256);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256(x));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0x100,0,8, 0,192,0,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256(x));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(-1,0x100,0,8, 0,0,32,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256(x));

   /* Set arrays for mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2:                          */
    alignas(32) static const uint32_t indx[16]   = {   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   3,   2,   2,   2,   2,   1,   1,   0,   0};
    alignas(32) static const uint32_t lz_msk[16] = {   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  64,  64,  64,  64, 128, 128, 192, 192};
    alignas(32)              uint64_t tmp[4]     = {   0,   0,   0,   0};
    printf("\nmm256_lzcnt_si256_v2\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 257; i++){
        printf("x=");
        x = bit_mask_avx2_lsb(i);
        print_avx2_hex(x);
        printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(x, tmp, indx, lz_msk));
    }
    printf("\n");

    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,0, 0,15,1,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(x, tmp, indx, lz_msk));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0,0,8, 0,0,0,256);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(x, tmp, indx, lz_msk));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(0,0x100,0,8, 0,192,0,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(x, tmp, indx, lz_msk));
    x = _mm256_set_epi32(-1,0x100,0,8, 0,0,32,0);
    printf("x=");print_avx2_hex(x);printf("lzcnt(x)=%i \n", mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2(x, tmp, indx, lz_msk));

    return 0;
}
```

The output suggests that the code is correct:

```
$ ./a.out
mm256_lzcnt_si256
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  lzcnt(x)=256 
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000001  lzcnt(x)=255 
...
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  lzcnt(x)=129 
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  lzcnt(x)=128 
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000001 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  lzcnt(x)=127 
...
x=7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  lzcnt(x)=1 
x=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  lzcnt(x)=0 

x=0000000000000000 0000000000000000 000000000000000F 0000000100000000  lzcnt(x)=188 
x=0000000000000000 0000000000000008 0000000000000000 0000000000000100  lzcnt(x)=124 
x=0000000000000100 0000000000000008 00000000000000C0 0000000000000000  lzcnt(x)=55 
x=FFFFFFFF00000100 0000000000000008 0000000000000000 0000002000000000  lzcnt(x)=0
```

---

Function `mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2` is an alternative version of the same function,
but now the pointers to the lookup tables and the scratch array are passed with
the function call. This leads to [clean assembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/RB9gAQ) 
(no stack operations), and gives an
impression which instructions are needed after inlining `mm256_lzcnt_si256`
in a loop.

With gcc 8.2 and options `-m64 -O3 -march=skylake`:

```
mm256_lzcnt_si256_v2:
        vpxor   xmm1, xmm1, xmm1
        vmovdqu YMMWORD PTR [rdi], ymm0
        vpcmpeqq        ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vmovmskpd       ecx, ymm0
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsi+rcx*4]
        lzcnt   rax, QWORD PTR [rdi+rax*8]
        add     eax, DWORD PTR [rdx+rcx*4]
        vzeroupper
        ret
```

In a loop context, and with inlining, `vpxor` is likely hoisted outside the loop.

Comment: I think this is one of those times when store/reload beats ALU, because store-forwarding latency can run in parallel with index-calculation (vpcmpeq / movemask / bsr latency).  See my answer.

Comment: That is a good point. The `ymm` store can start even before the `vcmpeq`. I have updated the answer to redirect the reader to your answer.

Comment: Interesting idea to use a LUT instead of `x - bsr(movemask)`.  It might even be lower latency.  Looking back at this, I feel like `lzcnt` on the mask should have avoided the `31-` with BSR, and maybe made it branchless in my version.  Memory-source 64-bit `lzcnt` is nice (but unlaminates an indexed addr modes on Skylake, where the false dependency is removed :/)

Comment: The `indx` LUT can be 8-bit without costing any extra instructions.  (MOVZX vs. MOV is free on Intel and Ryzen and only 1 byte longer, and I don't think indexing a static LUT with PIE/PIC would change the fact that you'd want a separate load before a memory-source LZCNT, even if you made it `uintptr_t[]`.)  `lz_msk` should stay 32-bit though to allow folding that load, so the total space saving is pretty small.  And we can't do an 8-bit `add al, [rdx+rcx]` because the result can be 256, which doesn't fit.  Plus partial registers suck.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for your comments. [Godbolt results](https://godbolt.org/z/N8J8Vv) with 8-bit LUTs, which confirms you comment. Can you explain what you mean by: *you'd want a separate load before a memory-source LZCNT* ?

Comment: I was thinking about doing the address calculation with ADD instead of using an indexed addressing mode.  But I was getting mixed up with what the `lzcnt reg,mem` was indexing: it's into `tmp`, not a static table.  So you could maybe do `add rdi, [rsi + rcx*8]` (stays micro-fuses because of read/write dst reg) / `lzcnt rax, [rdi]` (stays micro-fused even on SKL because non-indexed addr mode).  But then you need `const uintptr_t indx[]`, and you need to convince C that you're adding byte offsets, not scaled array indices.  Either with `char*` or casting to `uintptr_t` and back.

Comment: But more likely `tmp` is on the stack and the compiler doesn't have its address in a register.  So it would just MOV or MOVZX load and use an indexed addr mode for lzcnt.  With a static table, you'd have either a RIP-relative LEA to create `rsi`, or `movzx eax, [indx + rcx]` which doesn't even need a SIB byte :)  Compilers probably wouldn't put `indx[]` on the stack from immediate data because that would be 4x `imm32` .   `lz_msk` would be efficient to store from immediates because of half of it being zeros, if it was a byte array.  But anyway, static rodata is fine.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid I don't have enough x86 
background knowledge to understand all the details, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are also asking for more elegant (i.e. simpler) way to do this: on my computer, your code runs as fast as the one below. In both cases it took 45 milliseconds to compute the result for 10 million 256-bit words.

Since I was filling AVX registers with (four) randomly generated uniformly distributed 64-bit integers (and not uniformly distributed 256 integers), the order of iteration through the array had no impact on the result of my benchmark test. Also, even though this is almost needless to say, the compiler was smart enough to unroll the loop.

```
uint32_t countLeadZeros(__m256i const& reg)
{
  alignas(32) uint64_t v[4];
  _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)&v[0], reg);

  for (int i = 3; i >= 0; --i)
    if (v[i]) return _lzcnt_u64(v[i]) + (3 - i)*64;

  return 256;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: as it can be seen in the discussion below my answer and in my edit history, I initally took the approach similar to the one of @PeterCorbes ([but he provided a better optimized solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49217087/7519513)). I changed my approach once I started doing benchmarks because I completely overlooked the fact that practically all of my inputs had the most significant bit located within top 64 bits of the AVX word.

After I realized the mistake I had made, I decided to try to do the benchmarks more properly. I will present two results below. I searched through the edit history of my post and from there I copy-pasted the function I submitted (but later edited-out) before I changed my approach and went for the branched version. That function is presented below. I compared the performance of my "branched" function, my "branchless" function and the branchless function that was independently developed by @PeterCorbes. [His version is superior to mine in terms of performance - see his excellently written post that contains lots of useful details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49217087/7519513).

```
int countLeadZeros(__m256i const& reg){

  __m256i zero = _mm256_setzero_si256();
  __m256i cmp = _mm256_cmpeq_epi64(reg, zero);

  int mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp);

  if (mask == 0xffffffff) return 256;

  int first_nonzero_idx = 3 - (_lzcnt_u32(~mask) >> 3);

  alignas(32) uint64_t stored[4]; // edit: added alignas(32)
  _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)stored, reg);

  int lead_zero_count = _lzcnt_u64(stored[first_nonzero_idx]);

  return (3 - first_nonzero_idx) * 64 + lead_zero_count;
}
```

**Benchmark number 1**

I will present the test code in pseudocode to make this short. I actually used AVX implementation of random number generator that does the generation of random numbers blazingly fast. First, let's do the test on the inputs that make branch prediction really hard:

```
tick()
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
   // "xoroshiro128+"-based random generator was actually used
   __m256i in = _mm256_set_epi64x(rand()%2, rand()%2, rand()%2, rand()%2);

   res = countLeadZeros(in);  
}
tock();
```

For 10 million repetitions, the function from the top of my post takes 200ms. The implementation that I initially developed requires only 65ms to do the same job. But the function provided by @PeterCorbes takes the cake by consuming only 60ms.

**Benchmark number 2**

Now let's turn to test that I originally used. Again, pseudocode:

```
tick()
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
   // "rand()" represents random 64-bit int; xoroshiro128+ waw actually used here
   __m256i in = _mm256_set_epi64x(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand());

   res = countLeadZeros(in);  
}
tock();
```

In this case, the version with branches is faster; 45ms are required to compute 10 million results. The function by @PeterCorbes takes 50ms to complete and my "branchless" implementation requires 55ms to do the same job.

I don't think that I dare to draw any general conclusions out of this. It seems to me that the branchless approach is better as it offers the more stable computation time, but whether you need that stability or not probably depends on the usecase.

**EDIT: the random generator**.

This is an extended reply to comment by @PeterCorbes. As I stated above, the benchmark test code is just pseudocode. If anyone is interested, how I actually generated the numbers, here is a quick description.

I used xoroshiro128+ algorithm which was released into public domain and which is available [at this website](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it). It is quite simple to rewrite the algorithm with AVX instructions so that four numbers are generated in parallel. I wrote a class that accepts the so-called initial seed (128 bits) as parameter. 
I obtain the seeds (states) for each one of four parallel generators by first copying the initial seed four times; after that I use jump instructions on i-th parallel generator i-times; i = {0, 1, 2, 3}. Each jump advances the internal state J=2^64 steps forward. This means I can generate 4*J numbers (moooore than enough for all everyday purposes), four at a time before any parallel generator starts to repeat a sequence of numbers that were already produced by any other generator in a current session. I control the range of produced numbers with `_mm256_srli_epi64` instruction; I use shift 63 for first test and no shift for the second one.

Comment: You need  `alignas(32)   uint64_t v[4];` if you're going to use an aligned-store intrinsic.  And BTW, both your version and the question branch, so could mispredict if the input isn't a uniform distribution (i.e. if the high qword isn't almost always non-zero).  But if that is the case, taking advantage of that with branch prediction is pretty good.

Comment: You're right, I added alignas to the sample straight away. Initially I tried to come up with a function without branch, but I could not match the performance of mine/OP's function (I did not benchmark the others). No matter what I tried, in best cases my function was ~20% slower than the one I posted in the reply. I was almost surprised because I was sure that branchless function will be significantly faster.

Comment: @PeterCordes this is the fastest version of branchless function I could come up with. See any room for improvement? (never mind that if clause, that can be removed with small tweak)
https://pastebin.com/XeBWAmXU

Comment: With a uniform *input* distribution, you will get almost no branch mispredicts because the high qword only has a 1 in 2^64 chance of being 0.  Counting only it will be much faster than checking everything branchlessly.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, I completely understand that. But as I said in the post I was testing this with uniformly distributed 64-bit integers and the function with the branch was nevertheless faster. That's what surprised me. See my comment which I posted 1 second before your reply; I pasted the link to branchless function there.

Comment: Your branchless version is very similar to my answer; I used basically the same strategy, using `n - lzcnt(movemask)` or `bsr` to index an array.  But I used a uint8_t array to avoid needing shifts, because `movzx` is cheap.

Comment: Anyway, I don't find it surprising that branchy beats branchless when the branches predict perfectly.  Fewer instructions and a shorter critical path is a nice win.  In your benchmark, were you looping over a giant array in memory, or looping multiple times over a smaller array (that fit in L1d cache), or generating the vectors on the fly with an AVX2 xorshift+ or some other PRNG?  If looping over memory, both versions are probably close to limited by memory-bandwidth bottlenecks.

Comment: Giant array in memory, filled with precomputed numbers. You are probably right about memory bandwith having a too large effect on this benchmark, yes.

Comment: @PeterCordes I actually wrote AVX implementation of xoroshiro128+ a while ago so I could quickly repeat the benchmark now without large arrays: the results of the benchmark are the same; the bandwidth was not a bottleneck after all.

Comment: Nice update with the benchmarks, thanks for testing mine. :)  But `_mm256_set_epi64x(rand(), rand(), rand(), rand());` isn't really an AVX2 PRNG, if you actually wrote it that way.  [I used an AVX2 `xorshift+`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323845/whats-the-fastest-way-to-generate-a-1-gb-text-file-containing-random-digits/324520#324520) that runs 4x 64-bit PRNGs in parallel in elements of a `__m256i`, for a case where performance was more important than quality (like this case; anything that defeats branch prediction is fine).  Only AVX512 has rotates; AVX2 has to emulate them.

Comment: I wrote a class that accepts single 128-bit seed as parameter. The seed is copied four times in the constructor (once per "parallel generator"), and then jump instructions are used {0, 1, 2, 3}-times. Each jump advances the internal state J=2^64 steps forward. This means I can generate 4*J numbers, four at a time without repeating sequences. Works fine for various purposes. I started with xoroshiro128+ implementation in C and rewrote it with AVX intrinsics. The original implementation with corresponding jump instructions is published here: http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/

Comment: Oh, so you don't literally use `_mm256_set_epi64x` on a scalar function inside the inner loop.  So that's not nearly as slow as what you wrote in your question.  But still, `xorshift128+` is faster (and somewhat lower quality) than `xoroshiro128+`, especially in SIMD without AVX512 for rotates.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I had the implementation for xoroshiro128+ ready at hand because I wrote and tested it for some other project in the past. :) I'll edit the answer and add a brief description. Seems like my "pseudocode" was not "pseudo" enough, hah. :)

Comment: @PeterCordes I quickly benchmarked the generator. It seems like 30ms are needed to produce 4*10e6 random numbers. If I substract that time from benchmark results above, the ratio of execution times of our branchless algorithms becomes about 4/5 (your function is faster). Benchmark seems OK, but I'll re-check it and edit the answer when I have the time. BTW, would you have any idea why execution times of branchless algorithms in first test are longer than in second test? Does _lzcnt_u64 produce result faster for larger numbers? I launched tests several times and the difference was always there.

Comment: That's an interesting and useful benchmark, actually.  Different strategies will be more or less friendly to surrounding code that bottlenecks on ALU throughput or latency, rather than the actual throughput of the vector lzcnt itself.  The extra ALU uops in Wim's version to shuffle instead of generate an index were a definite downside in that respect.

Comment: `_mm256_srli_epi64` isn't `%2`, really.  I assumed you meant `_mm256_and_si256` with `set1_epi64(1)`.  xoroshiro already bottlenecks on vector ALU shift throughput, I think, so adding another shift is probably what slows it down.  What CPU are you testing on?  `vpsrlq ymm,ymm, imm8` has only 1 per clock throughput on Haswell (port 0 only), but 2 per clock throughput on Skylake (port 0/1).  Of course on Skylake, it competes for port 1 against `lzcnt`.  Anyway, try using an `and` for your mod 2 if you're mostly bottlenecked on port0 throughput.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a version which is not really "elegant", but faster here (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)) :

```
#define NOT_ZERO(x) (!!(x))

#ifdef UNIFORM_DISTRIBUTION
#define LIKELY(x)           __builtin_expect(NOT_ZERO(x), 1)
#define UNLIKELY(x)         __builtin_expect(NOT_ZERO(x), 0)
#else
#define LIKELY(x)           (x)
#define UNLIKELY(x)         (x)
#endif


inline unsigned int clz_u128(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, int not_a, int not_b) {
    if(UNLIKELY(not_a)) {
        if(UNLIKELY(not_b)) {
            return 128;
        } else {
            return (__builtin_clzll(b)) + 64;
        }
    } else {
        return (__builtin_clzll(a));
    }
}

unsigned int clz_u256(__m256i packed) {
    const uint64_t a_0 = (uint64_t)_mm256_extract_epi64(packed, 0);
    const uint64_t a_1 = (uint64_t)_mm256_extract_epi64(packed, 1);
    const uint64_t b_0 = (uint64_t)_mm256_extract_epi64(packed, 2);
    const uint64_t b_1 = (uint64_t)_mm256_extract_epi64(packed, 3);

    const int not_a_0 = !a_0;
    const int not_a_1 = !a_1;

    if(UNLIKELY(not_a_0 & not_a_1)) {
        return clz_u128(b_0, b_1, !b_0, !b_1) + 128;
    } else {
        return clz_u128(a_0, a_1, not_a_0, not_a_1);
    }
}
```

It splits a bigger problem into smaller ones and uses the fact that it is incredibly more likely for higher bits to be non-zero than lower bits if the vector distribution is uniform.

Just add a `#define UNIFORM_DISTRIBUTION` if uniform distribution is expected for extra performance.

Comment: You're assuming a uniform distribution.  This is often not the case; in many problems where it's interesting / useful to use an lzcnt, the *output* is approximately uniformly distributed in some range, e.g. in 0 .. 256.

Comment: Your vector indexing or variable naming is weird.  ` _mm256_extract_epi64(packed, 3);` is the highest element of the vector, and if it's non-zero then it contains the bit we're looking for.  But you've called it `low_1`.

Comment: You're right it was confusing, I edited and now use neutral variables. I've also taken care of the uniform/non uniform distribution possibilities.