# pop() for built-in sets

Tags: set, nim-lang

The `HashSet` in `std/sets` has a `pop()` function that removes and returns an arbitrary element from the set.

Is there an equivalent for [*built-in* sets](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-set-type) in Nim? If not, is there some other recommended way to get an arbitrary element from a set? It doesn't matter if it's destructive (like `pop()`) or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this isn't the 'recommended' way to do this, obviously, but it does work, and it can even be worth the trouble if micro-optimising.

Nim sets, under the hood, are either the smallest uintx that fits (up to T.high - T.low = 63), or an array of uint8.

So the basic idea is:

```
import std/bitops
proc lowestElement[T](s:set[T]):T=
  if s.card == 0: raise newException(KeyError,"empty set")

  type SetT = (
    when sizeof(s)== 1: uint8
    elif sizeof(s)==2: uint16 
    elif sizeof(s)==4: uint32 
    elif sizeof(s)==8: uint64 
    else: array[sizeof(s),uint8])

  let theBits = cast[SetT](s)

  when sizeof(s)<=8:
    T(firstSetBit(theBits) + T.low.int - 1)
  else:
    var i = 0
    while theBits[i]==0: inc i
    T(firstSetBit(theBits[i]) + i*8 + T.low.int - 1)
```

Ive used `firstSetBit` but `countLeadingZeroBits` could compile to fewer instructions, albeit gives you the largest member in the set. You'd need to swap the iteration on the array as well:

```
  when sizeof(s)<=8:
    T(sizeof(s)*8 - countLeadingZeroBits(theBits) + T.low.int - 1)
  else:
    var i = sizeof(s) - 1
    while theBits[i]==0: dec i
    T(8 - countLeadingZeroBits(theBits[i]) + i*8 + T.low.int - 1)
```

You absolutely need to handle the empty set case somehow, and not just because of that infinite loop--those bit ops are undefined on 0. (ok, firstBitSet is defined on GCC, but only because it checks for zero for you)

This should work with any ordinal type, including holey enums

---

Ok below here i'm getting a bit silly, but i had to ask myself, is this actually faster, and can i vectorize it?

and i'm afraid i did this (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49213611/count-leading-zeros-in-m256i-word)):

```py
import std/[bitops,options]
import nimsimd

template highestSingleImpl[T](s:set[T]) =
  type SetT = (
    when sizeof(s)== 1: uint8
    elif sizeof(s)==2: uint16
    elif sizeof(s)==4: uint32
    elif sizeof(s)==8: uint64
  )
  let theBits = cast[SetT](s)
  if theBits == 0:
    none(T)
  else:
    T(sizeof(s)*8 - countLeadingZeroBits(theBits) + T.low.int - 1).some

template highestMultipleImpl[T](s:set[T]) =
  type
    HighT = ptr UncheckedArray[array[32,uint8]]
  when sizeof(s) mod 32 != 0:
    type
      LowT = ptr UncheckedArray[array[sizeof(s) mod 32,uint8]]
    let
      hiBits = cast[HighT](cast[LowT](s.unsafeAddr)[1].addr)
      loBits = cast[LowT](s.unsafeAddr)[0]
  else:
   let hiBits = cast[HighT](s.unsafeAddr)

  var i = sizeof(s) div 32 - 1
  while i >= 0:
    var
      vec = mm256_loadu_si256(hiBits[i].addr)
      nonzero_elem = mm256_cmpeq_epi8(vec, mm256_setzero_si256())
      mask = not mm256_movemask_epi8(nonzero_elem)
    if mask == 0:
      dec i
      continue
    let
      idx = 31 - countLeadingZeroBits(mask)
      highest_nonzero_byte = hiBits[i][idx]
    return T(i*32*8 + idx*8 + 8 - countLeadingZeroBits(highest_nonzero_byte) + T.low.int - 1 + 8 * (sizeof(s) mod 32)).some

  when sizeof(s) mod 32 != 0:
    i = (sizeof(s) mod 32) - 1
    while i >= 0:
      if loBits[i]==0:
        dec i
        continue
      return T(8 - countLeadingZeroBits(loBits[i]) + i*8 + T.low.int - 1).some
  return none(typedesc[T])



proc highestElement[T](s:set[T]):Option[T]{.raises:[].}=
  when sizeof(s) <= 8:
    highestSingleImpl(s)
  else:
    highestMultipleImpl(s)
```

i compared that to

```
proc naiveHighest[T](s:set[T]):Option[T] =
  var i = T.high.int
  whle i >= T.low.int:
    if T(i) in s:
      return T(i).some
    dec i
  return none(T)
```

with a few different versions of

```
block:
  type X = range[8..int16.high]
  doAssert sizeof(set[X]) mod 32 == 31
  var x:set[X]
  for i in 0..100:
    x.incl(rand(X))

  timeIt "not evenly vectorizable"
    var h:Z
    for _ in 0..1000:
      x.incl(rand(Z))
      h = z.highestElement.unsafeGet
      z.excl(h)
    keep(h)
```

and i got:

```
   min time    avg time  std dv   runs name
   0.061 ms    0.069 ms  ±0.004  x1000 mod 32 == 0, vectorized
  18.571 ms   22.570 ms  ±1.302   x219 mod 32 == 0, naive
   0.068 ms    0.072 ms  ±0.002  x1000 mod 32 == 31, vectorized
  18.892 ms   22.742 ms  ±0.485   x221 mod 32 == 31, naive
   0.791 ms    0.836 ms  ±0.016  x1000 mod 32 == 31, clz only
```

so, there you go.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to loop over the set, and then break after obtaining a single item:

```
func takeOne[T](items: set[T]): T =
  for item in items:
    items.excl(item)
    return item
```

You might want to add some error handling around empty sets.

Also I'd be surprised if this was the *recommended* way, so I will not accept my own answer (yet).

Comment: that's how to do it without bit-level hacks, but you forgot to `items.excl(item)`

Comment: Thanks @shirleyquirk, fixed. If you know the solution with bit-level hacks, I'm happy to see it!

Comment: added my answer, during which I realized, your answer will return 0 for an empty set, which will be either subtly or catastrophically wrong