# _BitScanReverse returns 0 when index is 1 which means according to MS "no set bits were found"

Tags: c++, msdn, intrinsics

Copied directly from MSDN...

```
unsigned char _BitScanReverse(  
   unsigned long * Index,  
   unsigned long Mask  
);
```

**Description**

Search the mask data from most significant bit (MSB) to least significant bit (LSB) for a set bit (1).

**Return Value**

Nonzero if Index was set, **or 0 if no set bits were found**.

According to the return value description if no set bit were found then Index=0. But what happens in the case where the mask = 1? Running the sample code that comes with the instruction inside the MSDN documentation, it returns also 0 which confuse the programmer since he does not know if "no set bit were found" or "index equals to 1" .

Am I understanding something wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misreading the documentation.  The *return value* is 1 or 0, depending on if there are nonzero bits in `mask`.  The index of the set bit is returned in `*Index`.  No confusion arises.

Comment: Exactly.  The function return value is the inverse of the ZF output of the `bsr` instruction, and `*Index` is the register result.  http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BSR.html.  (And BTW, Intel doesn't document this but AMD does: if the input is all zero, `bsr` doesn't modify the destination register.  So I think the intrinsic leaves `*Index` unset when it returns 0 for Mask==0.)

Comment: The Intel docs state that "If the content source operand is 0, the content of the destination operand is undefined." so you can't count on it having any particular behavior.  (In particular, any current behavior you observe may be change in the future.)

Comment: Right, Intel doesn't *document* the behaviour, but their existing hardware does implement it the way I described, and the way AMD documents it.  That's why `bsr eax, edx` has a "false" dependency on `eax`, even though it's write-only.  (And why [`popcnt`/`tzcnt`/`lzcnt` also have false dependencies on Haswell/Broadwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter), even though they really are write-only: they use the same execution unit.)

Comment: It's widely believed the Intel will continue to implement this unofficial behaviour indefinitely, the same way they keep implementing undocumented instructions like SALC since 8086, using up valuable opcode space in 32-bit mode, leading to longer opcodes for SSSE3 and later.  (http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=25)

Comment: Hey, its funny but right now reading your asnwers (and after an 8 hours of sleeping) I noticed that the function returning value is actually an unsigned char and not the pointer of "unsigned long *Index" I thought it was.... Yes now there is no confusion its clearly ! After a 10 hours of working maybe the human brain it stops thinking and seeing at all !! Thanks.