# How to help GCC to not insert xor before lzcnt?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86, clang

For this fragment of code (https://godbolt.org/z/s4PY44dha)

```
int foo(unsigned long long x)
{ 
    return _lzcnt_u64(x);
}
```

GCC generates 3 asm instructions

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
lzcntq  %rdi, %rax
ret
```

while clang generates only 2

```
lzcntq  %rdi, %rax
retq
```

Is it possible to change the implementation/signature of `foo` to help GCC understand that this `xor` instruction is useless? Why can't gcc perform such simple optimization itself?

---

The answer to this question [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter) explains that this `xor` may be useful for some old architectures to break so-called "false dependency" on the destination register. It even mentions that the issue it is supposed to fix is not present in the modern intel architectures starting from "Skylake-S (client)". I tried to
pass newer architectures to the GCC (for example `-march=rocketlake`, `-march=icelake-client`) but it still inserts "useless" `xor`.

In contrast, even for old architectures like `haswell` clang doesn't insert `xor`. This means that if one wants to get each bit of performance for certain architecture, then the insertion of `xor` should be controlled manually.

For example, with this inline assembly, I managed to get the code without `xor`.

```
int xorless_lzcntq(unsigned long long x) {
    unsigned long long res;
    asm ("lzcntq %1, %0" : "=r"(res) : "r"(x));
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The xor is not useless.  It breaks a false dependency on the destination register on some micro architectures.

Comment: so the question should be how do I get clang to add the xor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter)

Comment: Note that for different cpu e.g. `-march=znver2` the `xor` is not emitted.

Comment: @DanielLangr It answers it partially, at least now I understand why this xor is used. Apparently, gcc and clang are not perfect in the detection when it is required. It would be nice to control the insertion/omission of xor manually. Probably my best option is to use inline assembly.

Comment: @Curious Quite honestly, you shouldn't worry about this.  The `xor` is a zeroing idiom and handled entirely in the front end.  So unless your code is bottlenecked on frontend throughput (and it likely isn't), this is not the place you need to optimise.

Comment: Or just use `-march=znver2` for this file, if `-march=skylake` doesn't know that SKL fixed the lzcnt/tzcnt false deps (but not popcnt).  Inline asm defeats constant propagation, and the compiler won't know that the result is a small non-negative integer in the range 0..64.  That might or might not matter in any given use-case.  Also note that in a larger function, GCC can `lzcnt same,same` to sidestep the false dep without xor.

Comment: @old_timer: clang does use xor when it can see a loop within one function where this would create a loop-carried dependency.  But it's reckless about it otherwise, and assumes that the incoming RAX wasn't just used as a temporary result of a cache-miss load in the caller for example.

Comment: @PeterCordes I afraid that if I use `-march=znver2` then I will potentially lose other architecture-specific optimizations.

Comment: I can't think of a feature SKL has that Zen2 doesn't, which GCC would use directly. But more importantly would make other tuning choices.  But I was suggesting using it for just one file.  You could use `-march=native -mtune=znver2` - Zen2 has some similarity to Skylake, having full-width 256-bit vector hardware, although other tuning choices may differ.  Since getting perfect behaviour is apparently impossible with current GCC `-mtune=skylake`, it's worth benchmarking both ways to see which is faster for any specific code you might care about.

Comment: Report it here. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62011