# Collapse __mask64 aka 64-bit integer value, counting nibbles that have all bits set?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, avx, avx512

I have a `__mask64` as a result of a few AVX512 operations:

`__mmask64 mboth = _kand_mask64(lres, hres);`

I would like to count the number of nibbles in this that have all bits set (`0xF`).

The simple solution is to do this:

```
uint64 imask = (uint64)mboth;
while (imask) {
    if (imask & 0xf == 0xf)
        ret++;
    imask = imask >> 4;
}
```

I wanted something better, but what I came up with doesn't feel elegant:

```
    //outside the loop
    __m512i b512_1s = _mm512_set1_epi32(0xffffffff);
    __m512i b512_0s = _mm512_set1_epi32(0x00000000);

    //then...
    __m512i vboth = _mm512_mask_set1_epi8(b512_0s, mboth, 0xff);
    __mmask16 bits = _mm512_cmpeq_epi32_mask(b512_1s, vboth);
    ret += __builtin_popcount((unsigned int)fres);
```

The above puts a `0xff` byte into a vector where a 1 bit exists in the mask, then gets a 1-bit in the `bits` mask when the blown-up `0xf` nibbles now are now found as `0xffffffff` `int32`'s.

I feel that two 512-bit operations are way overkill when the original data lives in a 64-bit number. This alternate is probably much worse; it's too many instructions and still operates on 128 bits:

```
    //outside the loop
    __m128i b128_1s = _mm_set1_epi32(0xffffffff);

    //then...
    uint64 maskl = mboth & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f;
    uint64 maskh = mboth & 0xf0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0;
    uint64 mask128[2] = { (maskl << 4) | maskl, (maskh >> 4) | maskh };
    __m128i bytes   = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(b128_1s, *(__m128i*)mask128);
    uint bits = _mm_movemask_epi8(bytes);
    ret += __builtin_popcount(bits);
```

Comment: `_mm512_mask_set1_epi8` can be `_mm512_movm_epi8` (VPMOVM2B) which is significantly more efficient than a merge-masked broadcast into a zeroed register (could have at least used zero-masking, `maskz_set1`)).  But yeah, that was my first thought.  Four total front-end uops (if the all-ones vector mask can be hoisted), including the `kmovw eax, k1` on the cmp-into-mask result, pretty good for front-end throughput, but leaves the integer execution ports under-used if the surrounding code is bottlenecked on ports 0 and 5 (on Intel) or on SIMD ops on Zen 4.

Comment: I accepted harold's answer because it's beautiful, but the overall main loop is 10% slower with it, compared to your suggestion.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense; we need some context.  It should only cost at worst 9 uops vs. 4, on top of whatever else is in your loop, and doesn't compete for vector execution ports.  Or I guess 10 uops if you include a `kmov` to get `imask` out of a mask register.  Is your compiler using `kshift` and `kand` to do the shift/and in `k0..7` mask registers instead of the GPR where it needs the result for `popcnt`?  What compiler with what options, running on what CPU, and what surrounding code?

Comment: `__mmask64 mboth = _kand_mask64(lres, hres);` - If possible, do a zero-masked compare-into-mask to get the AND for free, unless you also need both masks later.  Like `_mm512_mask_cmp_epi8_mask`

Comment: I went back and looked at it again with a longer benchmark; the difference is not quite 10% but the non-vector solution is still slower. https://godbolt.org/z/v6YTxKso7 is the compiler and the code, Win10x64 if that matters, and this is the CPU: https://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Xeon/Intel-Xeon%206256.html

Comment: I very much appreciate the ```_mm512_mask_cmp_epi8_mask``` tip! I am not sure if I understood an earlier comment of yours correctly, what exactly did you mean by hoisting the all-1 vector?

Comment: Oh, 10% not 10x, I was distracted and misread your comment last time.  Yeah, 10% slower makes sense, especially if you're bound on front-end bandwidth (e.g. if data is hot in L1d or L2 cache).  Especially with the store/reload of `*needle_lo`, `*needle_hi`, and `*haystack` inside the loop since you didn't use local `unsigned int*` variables or `__restrict` to let the compiler know the pointers don't alias each other or the pixel data being loaded with loads that are allowed to alias anything.  Actually that's a loop-carried dependency through store-forwarding, probably a latency bottleneck.

Comment: Re: hoisting: I mean the compiler runs one instruction outside the loop to put a constant in a vector register, if you're doing this operation in a fairly tight loop (which it turns out you are, rather than just one of these and some non-inline function calls.) 
 https://godbolt.org/z/MbvzfPGxa shows what I mean, see the comments on `_mm512_cmpeq_epi32_mask(vboth, _mm512_set1_epi32(-1))` - and notice how that lets it use a vector register, instead of loading every time inside the loop when you passed a `__m512i*`!!

Comment: I also added `__restrict` so the updated pointers are stored once outside the loop.  (aka the stores are *sunk* out of the loop, compared to the C++ source which does `*haystack += vecsize;` inside the loop.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With just some scalar operations you can do this:

```
imask &= imask << 2;
imask &= imask << 1;
ret += std::popcount(imask & 0x8888888888888888);
```

The first two steps put, for every nibble, the horizontal AND of the bits of that nibble in the most significant bit of that nibble. The other bits of the nibble become something that we don't want here so we just mask them out. Then popcount the result.

The shifts could go to the right (as in an earlier version of this answer) or they could be rotates, whichever works out best.

---

Clang makes efficient asm from this version, with no wasted instructions other than [xor-zeroing ahead of `popcnt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter) which should go away with inlining since it can `popcnt same,same` even without planning ahead to have the result in EAX for the calling convention.

GCC does ok, but reorders the `&= mask` last so it's part of the critical-path latency, not in parallel with the shifts, despite our best efforts to make the source look like single asm operations to try to hand-hold it into making better asm.

MSVC is weird with this, turning it into right shifts, as well as doing the `&= mask` last like GCC.

```
// Clang compiles this optimally, hopefully also when inlining
// GCC still does the & mask last, on the critical path
// MSVC mangles this, with two right shifts despite the source going left, and deoptimizes latency like GCC
int count_nibbles(uint64_t imask)
{
    uint64_t mask = 0x2222222222222222;  // movabs, or hoisted out of a loop
    uint64_t shifted = imask << 1;   // LEA dst, [src+src] into a new reg
    shifted &= imask;                // AND
    shifted >>= 2;                   // SHR
    imask &= mask;                   // AND into original reg, in parallel with the shift/AND chain
    shifted &= imask;                // AND
    return std::popcount(shifted);   // POPCNT
}
```

This version also prevents clang from deoptimizing a shift or rotate into `lea reg, [0 + reg*4]` which is 8 bytes long and has 2-cycle latency on Alder Lake / Sapphire Rapids.  (https://uops.info/).

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAOykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzNIADqgKhE4MHt6%2BAaSp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXEm2mPZFDEIETMQE2T5%2BgXaYDpmNzQQlkTFxidIKTS1tuZ0TA2FD5SNVkgCUtqhexMjsHOYJYcjeWADUJglu0YRn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2Bfj%2BIIAdAjXtw/3AHoAccCMRDAoDAQXqhko4WGJjkwFCxjtEmMgANYg1DHNzY44IQzoAC0CE86GOaBYyTocQUxzCIIQL2IeGACAIx3wxG69T%2BQOOMLhCIA7oQEJSDEZSMcRcyeUyXsliKhovQUSKkccFF5osShXh4bRtQg8FQCPSSMcVU0oQp%2BcCAOJuPHjOjGrBUTBMC2K44ASWCygZ1JVADdMGxBA7jgBZIQANTx8OYwEw9KI2uQPJFTLw9K8yRlYoIErMqmOLFQYdOlmO5ZNZERDApnu9vtLL0DwcNyurkcYBD%2BYU5aC8ggA%2Bgw8NE1emJyw8KoJ92wwkIF4RwA2SQTzmGpEYlZ/Ez%2BKz3Y6X46bwQ7veVw%2BvAAixw0qjMH8/X%2B/ZjOFkvApVmGTDRAoMpWmS%2BZQhSGycqgVCIsctCoDCfxXte267pyCimuamAUmcL4HgoWJnG4ZHHFwf5XgKwTYHcXLjDKJgAKwWAoWzWBxpgsURgg4kwxzhLmPLAGh6HHECN4EHe2G4dBz4ho%2B1hKSR1EAcC8ZJgy9KYBGDCypgeDEFgxCyuKeZgeZpb1hWOFmaJMq/heV44WaCnmFuhGqRi6kSf5NHAncERPuJl5uXhBEJDc0Xeb%2BCT/gFSWBccQgABIAEphT5tZeQkL7wmpCXJSVArBXxmYkGyYQIo5DIGckzRiPQxolhKnYmu5AJEpShJhNlEUeWYeVEYVvnFSVEllSF2U8gQmwGe8IAgKkyRjoIECDfhx4JSe/ihfcMZaXiVBMHQGY4l4SjHBYsb%2BmY1okKoMqHIYwAggtGbMo9tovCOOJ0XcpAxs6eJtj6X1dkGIZ9hGUactEACeiLJMktCI2E70dW%2BAAcOMPiRSFIpy470Ao9Iii8V1/QwtDzIiyL4vwWx/QQnzDoIlIbJO06zmTC5LhumH3sRR57eeDFXqLuXeUtIA2rQECi05O2JQKGUAPIZQAGslApbqiiN2jKXDIETUIMMgiPZdJsmdZFilK2NrzkeclGqxpSHetamDAMxbGibW/6iaxL6ScCkiG8blFm5CjBW9l0ued5uN42n6cZzjfkpeV9XHI1YK0C11ntd9ShoC29sEDKvbhpjAZBp8l4eF4tAUmE4zehSsR5wXzW1CXfo0MQ4xV/iaacoJXgwoKXhwQhHUKMgzLoK3cTaih4TENlQJIiwEDmL%2BZgJA%2BGIvB1VI0vQZnwlCrJiHgABeLx4sB3g04hIcfscIC1kfFjbw/E7Q8KwPbh21EQZIxxQbHCoCqFEOEUKOCMAyC0tQEKMg6vwVAQ4XKXjmgtCB6BlqrXWgQYBhNPJV22n%2BPaB07gCleighQqA2BwnTMcNMW8fQcI6qQ7m%2B4GDJDnnnDqIoVQoMDiw44kZCD0kElgZIxJog8iYBieuqgSAxmiCI0sPoTQbDblyfMTBUbejMnKRg9U6bTmYQcVmlJDCIloNI0hnMFCsEwLYTxl5iRCRxKIIumNiQV30vUH2ABHTcPJ4YnkBMCN0Rd/HHG0KgZGbVLLHAjCPTIMpyr1wyR1KqwAarGjCMIzkm17EyOyUbU0KD8zHHKvhZsiNNSI2PPcEcXNxwECnDOOcCgBbLlXGYIWt4sI%2BU6Q8M8NthacjGi07ySdhqvnfD%2BDZH5aF4JysnfKxwKGkXOBRLgqts4CnoIJOqrEAG%2ByDj7MSvFPaRyRtHU25t47Wx2bbSZW0oovjljaYghyVbUXVlrXWSV9ZR3TCbWOPDLZfMlhpH594/mKSTrFaK9YwXAgEOjREYZUB4HQPSWMGsEwMgQv2Yg4iMgoI6s7Cu4xDC4ORbs4a3lFnoG2ey3eyID5bOPgSTAyNQYvVYRUj%2BpZGkkFMofH%2Bf9rCALGaLUBvL0IEOIItAgxCVowjIYc3K1D0BnMOvtOJDDgQAE1YWKmuugHEIoSAYhlD1BRZovQ8k5syponM6Zn2OJIYNkcrTp04XgCMFMJHvXBJTEeHNOR2nIceWZOytUGTIf0vm85FwjKDGuCAb4uAADFj6SBYlufwJanwlpxiWjQDazUzPoSeY%2BZpXyJp6TzAZ/MR7yXGTJSZarxaJ2dns0ayksXYBxbtHZKyRq7OnZRDVV4M1EJIQagRRqqHFq4Pug9h6j3NtPK2rpPqBHZsGROaIi4xmov3GNaZp4JboQXbLXVy0gUgvrGAgUKpiDPQJDCTAVBW7ozHcpTl%2BzAU4OBcrd2q78GYHmtqjd%2Bq1rboXWso9uHj28tPZa7pWbebXsBoOu2I7zWvqluO6Dk7KHHLdvFNWwJLkPP9hYDQ9zRIACpJCh3AfjV5dqzDwotlbQUBk7ht3XsENRmBIOUPo0u12eIqITQud7a5Ac7kqRDk8gULyjbplmihwhct%2BG9J3as1Omd7M4xPRaw6x9XBmiIxe3pV7%2BaiGIMQRGE5UgtBAvQCjw6n2ju%2BfMqTHCU6qDwwljTNHLwPsFOgf5HKDYCFM3OvlwI0SYkLFzLAMoWUtmaBSXz/n9QiJJU4FgO9gRMNjZXGBBpFzP0yZmJg6XuroFMFFiZaKfAYro/%2BDAPLcvoVS1V5GssRsUQm%2BpAUx1rzXUBpJXEsZgxBSfORHZE3FI6hRCpWbSGfaoZ1XqqzG1DtUOywoJzZ6HjtoQp6eY6AIATgnKoHGW4Jx3gnCsU4/hyKg65KBj7ByJzxjcBOBM2AMrTKBI8S2zwXaGkXIIVkDBvi/Bc/sKgnpjgw6EHDhHWUCdPC8CcMiI4cd49igT2oSg237DRzTl4ZFftbnp2ERnNxmctnc4dUXVrcRSj9tAl0brK6realzaktJMmgZoMgPAg4IPntHJe0jPnmj%2BYnHzhgYWRYReo3MobcFwj0ji4lvD53xzpGAOECkyEUHu/end/Z2GHuO4YM713SEBDvU99qHwy3gQTh6/1g3AWvA7h0hDmgQeMlyGCMEGpViBDHBKF4CsliFTp6Tw%2By3BAcb3lm4paP6XZsTgT5HItNcxrgXS8xYax3m3oUYXHgkWpMw9ycTjZRhAQSI2SF4mRLiXirepvSJQBAzbAiAo/CsmZb5xDwA/TrhBgY7IFHpKxliDKEDABwAsSgKT9%2B%2BuU3RAkGA4PlCTmPdeG/ZQgESklKwa%2Bx78/HncEAs2pWPgMoGg7eW4E2f6mkiYyYPC98dMz89IVejIgkO4I%2BnIgcnYBkE89Io%2BBWWI/0uIJasCVodwe2Zml26GN25Cd2qyD2J6%2B%2BAI3uAKC2dYZ2E0UKwI4QLSmY1Mz%2Btece9eiemYE8fos2NWnIqueA6umu6SFkx0jW0kFeo4ve82J2bsS2mm0B2kfBG2wIbg22jWP%2Br%2BABQB4eLAoB4BkBuKio0m5BYuhGDhr2xO32joEQcgcOE4XaJGva84deLuXgpuj6ICkW7KqWD2ike69uh6ju0WzBmWMW9ouWjwCEGgMYzMTSAAKp5JkdqIjIIEwBWPitbMVMvN0FiI6BgNEJ4NhChsgsAPaIwWtufKaBdCQSzNYvTEiEoOUAStAMgMgACM1nkQUaoNMuhHvAcofDHrWCxGYO3ixGkSxG4AwKxG4EOFsjshJNMf1scAACRgGzFpHfzZS/yHyEQqoHKQGnA7JnEfjHEPQQCQHt5mCXGHLqrJGubT6NaojogYhFZoAnAQA6KTwuI4gHCSo%2Bgzj0CDzHQyj%2BicJeDpiPbZTfbSRcBmDKHmEThtQThV7eRokjgYnKHvH3KaHJYYRW6OJ/5HY%2BA4nih4mqHLo7jnbxHHb0mliMk0mnZx4EaubC5UCWqarmZoaWZbrWa0FZY25PZs5uaClC74BUAcBrC0CcAsS8B%2BAcBaCkCoCcDkSWAqQsKbDbC1gJA8CkAECaDKlrAYggAJAJCfD2lOnOkulbj6CcCSAalWk6mcC8AKAgBgGWlanKmkBwCwAwCIAoCSq0hkAUCAHRnXwgDABVDzE0C0B3z%2BnAnemXDMD%2BacDmk5nNCIwazRDaC8j5m8BUjwway0yIzelYA6LABuDNT%2BncC8BYApjADiDBmkDci8iRrpjemYCqDdBzw7Dmkji1Del0wqJFkeBYDemgiGgVlrBUAGANEJga4igawT6anmn8CCAiBiDsBSAyCCCKAqDqA9m6BcD6BvQoDWDWD6Azj%2BmQBrAGgCCtnEgawnzEjvCEQBGPmWBmDcbEjwhbA/D5Q87EhoFhiek6nZKshYCvkQBrBdA9DOAQCuBTB%2BC3khDzBlAVB6AFAZACA4XEVpCkUMCDCEVLA1B1C9CzDkW3noX1B9AtA0XDCVC2BMWeDtB6AsocUEVcUSBoUbAsyiXukcDqmkCanam6kcDHDQWJ7AADGUQOmPG4CEBWh7CnK8BBlaCgKkC2n2mOkunmX2lumqkcDwUsAgCLGfAACckg/gOMVQXArlGgZgjlGgt5clvAClfpAZFpVpawYZkZl8MZ5AlAkViZYYyAqME4YYXAjlE4CQ/gP2O4fAdAGZlA0Q2ZNUeZbZpAhZ/mJZZZDgFZpAVZg4NZ6M9ZmAjZzZRcrZ5pHZb03Z2pfZPQUaQ5I5yAY5VVk51l5pM5YI/m85Ow2pS5dlbZq565Cgm5mA25u5VVB5wggSJ50g61F5ag3pugCQd5RgD5Bplgz5oE8A75sImQX5S0pgp1FgIFxw35D0xIzQy8IAdwCY2sLEGJAViFJKg5b59F/ZmF2FfFuQeFLYnFiw3FJF9QzF%2BQlF9QMNRFLFtQoNDQvFOQuFINGFWN/QqNdFglrQENuNJNRNlQYlxpJ5KpapXpPZClSlieLACg8VWSKVjp/gByWlRAZkulKw%2BloVawzIPWIwqFUltlIAkgjlnwGgcxXAf2OMZgKV/gfl3pgVtgwVBl1pxldpDpFlFlVlnACQDN8lvpIVwZYVEZEASAsVcQ0V8ZSuiZzWHlvl2V6ZdIeVBVuZdZxVpVxZpZ5ZxVNVggdVftXVjVXgTZLZVV7VRgnV7Zxk/ZvVPZw5o5UIQ1ggU5PZY1c5GAU1%2BlrIs1PA81TAG5W5O5jAa1sgR54gp5O1Sge115IA8xkuJ1VgZ1M5KFV19QX5P5z1/5%2BUgFD1T1YF71kFT4ylkgxIcF/1cQSFQNEtrFmQLgLYiN%2BFpQIlt58NmQiNu9xQwlsNAlGN%2BN7FpNONJ9DFAg59lNAl2N/FLFswd9py6wNNkl1lMl/lPpil09kob0lE/gctnwXAPN%2BAfNppellthlNp%2BtZlhtzpktZtAVFt/pgZwtUlZgyDP9QtVtaw2S6QzgkgQAA%3D%3D) for this and several other versions (including a portable version of chtz's ADD/ADC trick).  Using `asm("" : "+r"(imask))` at a certain point in the function can force GCC not to deoptimize the order of operations, but that could stop it optimizing this as part of a larger loop.

Writing this with multiple operations on the same source line doesn't hurt anything for Clang, and doing it this way still didn't stop GCC from screwing it up, but this does illustrate what optimal asm should be like.  You might prefer to compact it back up into fewer C statements.

---

GCC's reordering to group shift-and-AND together is useful in general for AArch64, where `and x1, x0, x0, lsr 2` is possible.  But even then, instruction-level parallelism would be possible while still only using 3 AND instructions, two with shifted operands.  [GCC/Clang/MSVC miss that optimization](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMxmpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZgCcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BQemZjgJhEdEscQnJtpj2JQxCBEzEBLk%2BflK19dlNLQRlUbHxiSkKza3t%2BV3j/YMVVaMAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/uHI3lgA1Cb%2BbjGEJ9gmGgCCO3sHmMen4/iCAHQIl9d3twD0f0OhwAtCwWsgvv4ACItFgANyS70kwKYh34xEOClEBgxyEEhwgtDwAGsnqoABwANkO6VSaC8giWPwBh1QBAQ8QA7nglIcbjcNghKZJDhFMOgFIciIc0KkAJ5S1CHVFwzAOEjKhjoQ4IBQ%2BQ4xOUETAKH7MwEEYiGBQGY2s1KOMG0ZUKFgGpjIYmKw5ub0IQzoYEITzatAsVJ0eKS8JSjmHYh4YAIAiHfDENUNc32x1iQ7c9kygxGUh5jnp2NPVLEVAxehuzlMSV6mLA1AOvBOzEIPBUAiSjXV5rG03/QEAcTcvvGdGdWComCYfYrhwAkiFlIcO1XUKq2IIswBZIQANV9YOYwBN3qx6c5sZ5hy8qRL%2BYQXYx6eAJbMrIYUs5SpKKkLSLk8n48saxAKO8PzhCm9KCAA%2BgweAxLWJqISweCqIha7KHC/gQF4cHCohKYdo2xJMrcJgAOxWLcQJAsRgikSmYIKF6JxQocGiqGYAmCUJwlmCcFhAiyLA7kwMQjjcTGPiRkhkV2PbGtq3GbhxXGnCcvpcGJTEsiE2DyRKBAliYACsFgKBs1h2aYVk8XBSqohEd6fj8CkAixBBsapvbis8LnacclhaZRhkSYCR6npukqYKqf6cpgeDEFgGKvveckKQo3ZBRpZiUppFGcdFCmVZVLI3JEULeUx%2BVqcF3z%2BFc0KHKJ/jiVVvXVYCQgABIAEoNUCZVccVmnaRVfV9TVdWboISokIm4S5l5jGNQV6nhSVHUTbNc1GYCtX1VtQLpgQ6x/q8IAgLSCEEBATWFUy3VmrR52/DcLJxb6VBMHQkrSl4vIWAeK4/tWxCqCW%2ByGMAUo3SDcaDqBS3SiZNykFmE6%2BnOC5LuyTx4Vp267owKaGsqqSpLQcrhEjJO8RS5KHGFBjjI%2BDD0AokqpY%2BvLhESEQum60ropsm4EDBtxwTKaxIShaF85h2FEUpKkTdRdz0WNkWcXtml3SAg60BAE3fu9PUssNADyw0ABpzSy1KGsOJZcMghy2owyBygbfkBa9u2aZbYV6XphxcDbMW%2Bwu8aYF%2Bxw2Z%2B4XiV5znxyKHsml7Pt%2BwwAcGxNxsdXx5JV9XNe1%2BSR2HAtLl/sBVq0PQzrZSzShoFqgUWeT1Zwkzq7ru8QIeF4tDauE4wLtqcRLTSIHt3UeaEG%2BLM0FBKah96l4pqiXhtqyXgpqgVDLliHLoFP8SYqgAjxAbAKNiwEDmKJZj%2BBzTCksuYYIz0AxGCSCeAxB4AAF5PF9HCMQXgngxlRF5AShwQDhS/hYYgn8I6USWHHRugJxgn3xmiasbp8qP0cEYGWdhL4xi3lQg2V0bqYgIOge6j0lbPTLuYakodxQ20%2Bt9FkCMaEKFQGwR0V5LwRCtMOZcXCGTkQYKkM%2BS8WacmrDQ9OEjDiYCwkuVEWBUjAhiOmP%2BI9VAkCzDEdR7JFxdjWNPVMPImB0wXFlDkf4RbhBHpkYuiD4KGGVLQPRj18QKFYJgWw0SgTAlFEqbEotgDAl7slBoScACOxF0x7gIGaUcbCZyJMONoVACou7dklKqKC2QSxnRHlUp4q1gDrWdOENRKYXp7CeEleIRpuw0IfGdYKhg5QNjlLrBWT1kKoXQgodWOE8JwjMJrViylyLaV1nRBi8kmLB02b/TiLUDqR2KqzESVzBJiVLuc/aPFcFGyjqcGOQjuo%2BUBPQZBydLJp2ThnJOwBrI8UIYcXORp84x0LqBYugcLqKQ2SpARGkOqm0HMQJ5xJraGTto7F281ATu0hQoAuvtYUlwRb5LWu8dqnNCpRZ47VsCdVxYCAQDNlRwlQHgCUhwDz22PJuS%2BO4uQJmoczOMYVe6zH3Ai3hU0OraXFLcqlfw34fwEjsHUmAFT43hpIrpiC/zsgfCQTKn80EYOsNggSWL8Gqv2ZdTA11iC3XYZwtsT0sV7X7oIx1dFvpZgAJpQpJrydASoALEGxZqbUxiezznTPiGVzR8REn/pILNIoNQ10OG01UAttFI2tKlKCsF8TDmekyfWCKWFusVsouZqsMJYWWeuAiEA%2BJcAAGLf0kFZSktEe1Qh7eSHtGgJ1CJol9Qpdxv49l4hW%2BC3Dm0LMQlBHa6z/JHJ1p9PZCkFUPMNjpZlrKPryvuaVSObVLgx0dQpet7qOEPS9dwn1fDWZcG/T%2B39f7Y4BtnTReWKbV0q3XTELCazDna22fuu5jK%2BEmw9WbNkmKradQISyGGcMdRtkwFQKeDMEPPMVTxdFaGsVe2nU6pOrrn2erpO%2Bo9X7/1se/TRwNc6ZlgfmWrbG26Ap7pnQepiR7r2Id0q8rqtsvmJ0/H8iwGhAWfgAFSSBBWC9medSWdRhcaOFv4%2BTT3viEP%2BmASOTWPbwqT%2Bloosm%2BUCxT6drBAs0yyCFw5mEutYabJRggP0XMrnXELVdONAfnf4VwPZuOgabeBtWohiDEDlIhdIrQZL0EE7uuDImg40t/FeTS3b2NsYfQcgrGBUUMtI9SJ%2BpoL20ZZDED0xInyKywCWWV6AWihhaCl1s6jeVOBYC/QEYiS191IW2R0UCnimpBm5dA6B1XoFMAimDu99QSdI%2BJKr5XmIFaSylkKmJtuvP2x8sF/0hZPGxo3H0B4NynShG4A2VXTt6jdK547gdGuPp8w2vzb7lEQA%2B5%2B%2Br4Wg00QXVQOchxEKITHJEOQbhEfLsbcrPjGFfuIWAAwLw2XYN4PgxtyrERJTFdUKVsr/2KtIvPst07LH6sBth0utVt2creilsa0WTxGxKEqJy6AyBkB/Am5iOUggmCqF1gpN%2BBJP5MCZ%2BYKyQRwpWQ0NZNwDAdcFK1Qiyqyu1uHAACQaEsmYLXlqDboM/txW1P4wfLaWMcBF9uBLa9QS79AKwMFO4JDrTj386hKDG%2B6T07W0BHAgHYw%2BYSlR7ENYuVC9B14Fn%2BiWFc%2BaEH83l0xRHfkuBmHJMinwiFXyIV%2B6dovcES9l54dswFl3ROHYZzKfrCoTYV6rzX1qLLhQHdZKrtFveN7V674C37bOotahi8B2jT62Evv889cHFzIeAeh5Fxdc5wjiggIjiklJEKkUQm7uib3aIEwIwf7UR%2Bjxo%2BPNgYausAT3GLo8Z4bgOxYUEAmAwJ8N8DDrsHDgRgjk/ohC/qNKAQ8F4EcHpHBIAcAbeqAWHhZnAV/ggU8HpCfsgeEKgVcOgfPlQHOiyG4EWCnPqnGvyieL6GIM6IApGNzgRjQMgHgFTMRiBiuvFtjosrjgQQwETlsiTnlmTh3vVqdiVjTr%2BsPgyJkPjsFLQAIEjCoTQuDmcohpvhTvIQwIoRENqOoWoaoWdqNldiyIhCrmtl3ohF4MKAlKmHfoYRnm%2BHICECEPoslEZmUF4KoKWPEE8O4Y4ZtvloII3p3slt3h1FYctrjvYSKF2iWBhlVlbpSF9jRp8pESdv6ItgaALn%2BOSGYoQFKHKKkDEvomEk8DdmDFeEoAQD7ICFJHCJAv4dKKAvEOAkSNAjLLjJzv0ilN4jLGABwJKLUfGqjMal0t6IYGyGWAjtYfEUPgihANyryksLETYVEXYcKBAL9l1j4CWJbntFVlhrFPQb/GAhAtApKDXkgocMKMUSmOnCTH%2BAfNGNTK1pjEqG4D2miBqDcK9t5vRivoxt6hvnVhTpxmqpoeRtthFDPldoSqKJgMFKDLyJsUsSKNKAfAAl3oNimGwXgBwVwZUhvHQaeGNn5BEf3mPt9hdstvZucfFLUYcPdoCG4E9mNpibYQkXsV3gcSwEcWkacWyhWH%2BICW9ovlxiQfgGQbKT2BwCsLQJwFZLwH4BwFoKQKgJwG9pYK5hIusNLDsDwKQAQJoEqSsMSIkOSO8BoGYPaRoMKFZP4P4FZN%2BtICqRwJIOqRadqZwLwAoCAJbuaZqUqaQHALAEgMwcAuQJQDGSMHCMgHTIhHCFwEkIhP4LRFYcQCwMKHwHQJBEGXHn6ecMwClpwKaWWS0HKPbDENoBmJWbwGGPkvbLzHKH6VgHYsAG4IwUGdwLwFgOeMAOIGGaQGmBmHgIWn6ZgKoGqGfFsKaXBHUE2foKhFaClh4FgH6ZaB2E2SsFQAYMAAoMeJwZyPbOURqaafwIICIGIOwF0DefIEoGoH6boJ6YjCgNYNYGubJPACsDNtkP2cCPbD%2BMCHdKYPqZYA6bwKKslryiaP%2Bd0JOc4BAK4FMH4KXsEFqPMMMAkCkEUFkAIBhTaWkBkERQwLhZUCMGMHUChY0BMG0J4B0KRXYPRX0K0FRYsGMIxSRVhbMJxQfgsDRSsIaRsA%2Bcqaqb6WOTqRwMqLmQ4SwAoEmYcGmYiFmQSLgIQBqCaUsLwKGVoPgqQNacVEiFwC6a6UkJILRFrkkBoFmvoJwD6aQCwBIBoJbhqVqbJYGcGWaRaSsJGYgCgIapGGQBQHsSFcAiALCMKMAFwIEJbjQLQEWZQDEKWetBWQOaQNWSlnWQ2Q4KuS2VTG2QzJ2ZgN2b2e3P2aaUOYjKOVqROQ4FOYhWObOfOcaKucuV6aaUSOYjWVuVsFqbua5QOQeUeSeWeReYwKuU%2BXeeII%2BbIIoCoOoGOboFwPoJ%2BZBVYJYL%2BUGZAABe2AIMBfbD/OBewtxPjl4N%2BdBV5bUgmFgHtRAKJXRU1ahehcxfkA5aEEJXhSANIIRQ0CRetQDdkFxSMEEGxa9Qxf0CRQ5ZDQ0BxQMD9dRQkNIAJUxXkJ0LYIxWDdUKJWsOJRIJJRwGqaQJ5bBZwHyMNAeA4cAGLjHP4O8GYHaZpfgEQBiLpfpf5VaYkIzYOq6f4JIOSGYCXpSFZVZI5d6dJV5QGbYL5QZeGYFRANGZFfEHGRFeGKFdFbmXCEURNlwLRBoOtUlSlSWWOTlR2VlRbXlY2VlUVYICVZbQ1eVV4D2X2aubVUYPVYOelJOdOa1XOcgAuZ1YICuVlb1RuXKANTuQmCNTwGNUwMeaeZgOeZeTNbIHNQ%2BdIE%2BUta%2BatYkBtUYF%2BVBTYL1Y9QdQ0Mdada8BdQTtdRYDBdqXdQheXchVDS4FqEDdhegLjXoCDcRR9Vjf3ZRcjYsOtfDb0LxYPXoBPQIIjb3ePVPZjTPTjaPSMLHKsEaRJZLaTeTf6XJbCLrSiIWIjDHLRHae8FwKzdpRzd/LHFzWGUZSZcze5d%2BmYNZbRLROSIbVmf4JLc5Xvd5XLSGdzZLWYNLRTRwA/YZSsLUpkM4JIEAA%3D).  AArch64 repeated-pattern immediates for bitwise instructions do allow `0x2222222222222222` or `0x8888888888888888`, so no separate constant setup is needed.

Comment: this is amazing, thank you!

Comment: Those can be rotate-right to allow BMI2 `rorx` to copy-and-rotate, avoiding `mov` to copy registers without needing APX extensions in future CPUs.  Shifting garbage into the top of the high nibble doesn't matter; we're doing that anyway for other nibbles, hence the mask.  `std::rotr(mask, 2)`.  This is still 6 front-end uops with RORX, more than the 4 uops from `vmovm2b` / `vpcmpeqd` / `kmovw` / `popcnt` using vector compares, but this can run on execution ports that don't compete with (512-bit) vector ops in surrounding code.

Comment: Or we could shift left for a mask of `0x88...` allowing `lea reg, [0 + reg*4]` (8 bytes, v. 6 for RORX) and `lea reg, [reg + reg]` (4 bytes).  https://godbolt.org/z/5GnarWxnn - LEA with a scaled index can run on p1/p5 on Ice Lake, p056 with 2c latency on Alder Lake, vs. p0/p6 for RORX with 1c latency.  But `lea` with `[reg+reg]` can run on any port.  LEA with `[0 + reg*4]` is still 1 uop with 1c latency on Zen 4, unlike 3-component.  https://uops.info/ (`LEA IS D32`)

Comment: So the best bet might be `imask &= std::rotl(imask, 2);` `imask &= imask << 1;` to allow RORX for the first, simple LEA (unscaled index) for the second.  As well as smaller code-size, that has more of a mix of execution ports, and equal critical-path latency to 2x RORX.  (Other ways are worse: Ice Lake has disabled mov-elim, Alder Lake has 2c latency for `lea reg, [0 + reg*4]`).  https://godbolt.org/z/8hsEfqqGb

Comment: Just for the record, `count_nibbles_mix` in https://godbolt.org/z/3z9KWjz8Y has I was going to post as an answer about micro-optimizing this.  That has rotate then LEA, and ANDs with the mask in parallel with the second shift, improving ILP.  (Thanks to clang for spotting that optimization which I applied in the source.)  But njuffa's answer makes that probably pointless.  I might still post something about the 2 AVX-512 instruction way, which is good on Intel if not bottlenecked on vector ALU ports, but other 512-bit uops are in flight anyway.

Comment: Having a hard time getting compilers to make optimal asm for `count_nibbles_mix`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/EzGE4MYq4 - `count_nibbles_mix_ILPv3` at the top is good with clang).  GCC still defeats the ILP improvement (doing the AND mask last).  Clang was previously deoptimizing a rotate to an LEA.  The latest version uses a mask of `0x22...`, shifting left by 1 with LEA and right by 2 with `shr`, with no extra `mov` instructions.  IIRC, clang used `shr` instead of `rorx` or `lea` when I changed to `<<1` first then rotr(2). 
I noticed it was still avoiding `mov` even with a shorter `shr`.

Comment: Another expression (which I rejected initially) is `((x & L) + ((x & ~L) >> 1)) & H`, it still doesn't look good but various things here have worked out differently than I expected

Answer (score 3):

[I would like to thank [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz) for spotting a critical error in my original answer.]

We can adapt Alan Mycroft's null-byte detection algorithm, which generates a byte `0x80` for every null byte found, and a byte `0x00` otherwise. We need to make three modifications. Instead of byte-wise masks we use nibble-wide masks. Instead of null nibbles we look for `0xF` nibbles by inverting all the nibbles first. And we need to prevent carry-out from nibbles to the next higher nibble as Mycroft's algorithm was designed to flag the *least-significant* null byte. Compiled with gcc 13.2 and flags `-O3 -march=core-avx2` fairly effient code results (check it out on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cej6naMfe)):

```
count_f_nibbles(unsigned long):
        movabs  rax, 8608480567731124087
        movabs  rdx, 1229782938247303441
        and     rax, rdi
        add     rax, rdx
        movabs  rdx, -8608480567731124088
        and     rax, rdi
        and     rax, rdx
        popcnt  rax, rax
        ret
```

```c++
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int popcount64 (uint64_t x) 
{
    int r = 0;
    while (x) {
        x = x & (x - 1);
        r++;
    }
    return r;
}

/* Adapted from Alan Mycroft's null-byte detection algorithm 
   newsgroup comp.lang.c, 1987/04/08,
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/2HtQXvg7iKc/xOJeipH6KLMJ
*/
int count_f_nibbles (uint64_t a)
{
    const uint64_t nibble_lsb = 0x1111111111111111ULL;
    const uint64_t nibble_msb = 0x8888888888888888ULL; 
    uint64_t t;
    a = ~a ;               // not-nibble: 0x0 where a has 0xf
    t = a |  nibble_msb;   // set nibble msbs to catch carry out from nibbles
    t = t -  nibble_lsb;   // msb = 0, if not-nibble was 0x0 or 0x8
    a = ~a & nibble_msb;   // extract msb, msb = 1 if not-nibble < 0x8
    t = a & ~t;            // msb = 1, if not-nibble was 0x0
    return popcount64 (t); // use std::popcount() where available!
}

int count_f_nibbles_ref (uint64_t imask)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while (imask) {
        if ((imask & 0xf) == 0xf) {
            ret++;
        }
        imask = imask >> 4;
    } 
    return ret;
}

/*
  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.lang.c/qFv18ql_WlU/IK8KGZZFJx4J
  From: geo <gmars...@gmail.com>
  Newsgroups: sci.math,comp.lang.c,comp.lang.fortran
  Subject: 64-bit KISS RNGs
  Date: Sat, 28 Feb 2009 04:30:48 -0800 (PST)

  This 64-bit KISS RNG has three components, each nearly
  good enough to serve alone.    The components are:
  Multiply-With-Carry (MWC), period (2^121+2^63-1)
  Xorshift (XSH), period 2^64-1
  Congruential (CNG), period 2^64
*/
static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;
#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

int main (void)
{
    uint64_t a, res, ref;
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        a = KISS64;
        res = count_f_nibbles (a);
        ref = count_f_nibbles_ref (a);
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("error: a=%016llx res=%d ref=%d\n", a, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

An alternative to the use of Mycroft's algorithm is to use yet another classical SIMD-in-a-register approach to per-subunit unsigned greater-than-or-equal comparison, by checking if each nibble is `>= 0xF`. This is ultimately based on the sum and carry bit vectors during addition, see comment for `vcmpgeu_nibble()`.

```c++
/* Set per-nibble msb when per-nibble unsigned a >= b is true. Based on
   Peter L. Montgomery's observation (newsgroup comp.arch, 2000/02/11,
   https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.arch/gXFuGZtZKag/_5yrz2zDbe4J):
   (A+B)/2 = (A AND B) + (A XOR B)/2.
*/
uint64_t vcmpgeu_nibble (uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    const uint64_t nibble_msb = 0x8888888888888888ULL;
    return ((a | ~b) - (((a ^ ~b) >> 1) & ~nibble_msb));
}

int count_f_nibbles_vcmpgeu (uint64_t a)
{
    const uint64_t nibbles_ff = 0xffffffffffffffffULL;
    const uint64_t nibble_msb = 0x8888888888888888ULL;
    a = vcmpgeu_nibble (a, nibbles_ff) & nibble_msb;
    return popcount64 (a);
}
```

The code gcc 13.2 generates for this is (see it at [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KMoo8jG5E)):

```
count_f_nibbles_vcmpgeu(unsigned long):
        movabs  rdx, 8608480567731124087
        mov     rax, rdi
        shr     rax
        and     rax, rdx
        sub     rdi, rax
        movabs  rax, -8608480567731124088
        and     rdi, rax
        xor     eax, eax
        popcnt  rax, rdi
        ret
```

Comment: C++20 has `std::popcount` in the `<bit>` header (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount); you don't need to roll your own, just compile with `-std=gnu++20` or `c++20`.  (oh, your code has a comment mentioning it.) 
 Also, recent GCC and Clang versions support `-march=x86-64-v3` as meaning AVX2+FMA3+BMI1/2, i.e. a Haswell feature set, a common baseline that all AVX2 CPUs except one unfortunate VIA model support.  Also `-march=x86-64-v4` is baseline AVX-512, like Skylake-X or later.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Microarchitecture_levels

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the comment in your code after posting my commenting and edited it.  I had first assumed that if you knew of it you would have used it, but having an old toolchain explains it.

Comment: Nice one.  Two 64-bit constants isn't great if they can't get hoisted out of a loop (especially if Intel uop caches are still slowish to fetch imm64 like in Sandybridge, according to Agner Fog's testing).  But if that's not a problem, this is 3 cheap integer uops vs. 512-bit `vmovm2b` / `vpcmpeqd`, so very close in front-end bandwidth and much cheaper in back-end.  I had thought about looking at the zero-in-word bithack to see if it could do this, but I expected it would be more operations than this, I forgot how good it was.

Comment: Me too, and I think from now on I'm definitely going to remember to have a look at it if it might be applicable, *before* spending too much time micro-optimizing something else. :P  As far a micro-optimizing this, a compiler could generate one constant from the other with `rorx` to copy-and-rotate.  Or even just with an LEA for a 3-bit left shift, but that's an 8-byte instruction vs. 6 for rorx.  If uop-cache fetch was a bottleneck, that could be a win.

Comment: If I comment out the `a = 0x7bf856948de350b4ULL;` line, I get: "error: a=4dac77ff27efb410 res=4 ref=3" (if I remove the `return` from the loop, I get 7 errors for the first 100 iterations.

Comment: The solution appears to be off by 1, if two consecutive nibbles contain an `f` (in that case `~a - nibble_lsb` borrows from the next nibble, which ruins the result.

Comment: The error is actually not for consecutive `f`, but `e` followed by `f` (or `0xeeef` will result in 4 instead of 1)

Comment: @chtz I think I got it fixed now. I had forgotten that Mycroft's detector is designed to catch the *least significant* null byte, and that there is a problem with carry-out for higher order bytes. My quick fix is to isolate the msb in each nibble, which unfortunately has a decidedly negative impact on efficiency. It's not horrible, but the bloom is off.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution which uses add with carry

```
int count_nibbles_carry(uint64_t imask)
{
    uint64_t ones = 0x1111111111111111;
    uint64_t odd = imask & ones;
#if 1
    // use this to force inline assembly (gcc/clang syntax)
    asm ("add %2, %0\n\t"
         "adc $0, %0" 
    : "=r" (odd) 
    : "0" (odd), "r" (imask));
#else
    // backup code (but also incompatible with MSVC, I guess)
    __uint128_t sum_with_carry = __uint128_t(imask) + odd;
    uint64_t carry = sum_with_carry >> 64;
    odd = sum_with_carry + carry;
#endif

    return std::popcount(odd & ones);
}
```

The idea is to first check every nibble which has the lowest bit set (`odd`).
If we add `odd + imask` we first set every lowest bit to zero, unless there is a carry from the previous nibble. Only the highest nibble might set the carry bit. This can be added with an `adc $0, %rax` to the (otherwise always unset) lowest bit.
Then we have to mask away all except the lowest bits (re-using the first `ones` mask) and do a popcount.

Clang actually figures out to produce just an `add` and `adc` from the `#else` part, but it creates another `xor rax,rax` before the `popcnt`

I added the source to Peter's godbolt link (from a comment to harold's answer): https://godbolt.org/z/G9q3dqoon

And here is some test code using code by njuffa: https://godbolt.org/z/1oPM9f1f9

Comment: MSVC on x86-64 doesn't allow `asm` blocks. I used this portable code (not great for performance, but demonstrates the principle): `#define ADDcc(a,b,cy,t0,t1) (t0=(b), t1=(a), t0=t0+t1, cy=t0<t1, t0=t0)  /* end of macro */
uint64_t ones = 0x1111111111111111;
uint64_t odd = a & ones;
uint64_t sum, carry, t0, t1;
sum = ADDcc (a, odd, carry, t0, t1);
odd = sum + carry;`

Comment: @njuffa: MSVC supports `_addcarry_u64` (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/intrinsics-guide/index.html#techs=MMX,SSE_ALL,AVX_ALL,AVX_512,Other&text=ddca&ig_expand=193) - this lets us get ADD/ADC from all thee major x86 compilers: https://godbolt.org/z/EcTnKr55E .  Since we only need carry-out, `sum = a+b; carry = sum < a;` also works; GCC and clang also optimize that, but MSVC does LEA / CMP / ADC which is close; less bad than `add` / `setc` / `movzx` / `add`.

Comment: The extra xor-zeroing before popcnt is because of [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21390165) - popcnt wasn't fixed until Ice Lake.  Compiling with `-march=znver4` or `-march=icelake-client` makes compilers avoid doing that.  It would be nice if they were smarter about ANDing into RAX so they can `popcnt rax,rax` (dst=src means there's no extra false dep on anything else); hopefully that would happen when inlining since they wouldn't need the result in a specific hard register for the calling convention.