# What's the name of the popcount function in Julia?

Tags: julia

What's the name of the function that tells you how many bits are set in some variable? This surely already exists in `Base` or maybe some standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [Keno Fischer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-users/B_5SYRaY9YI/0Auz3c_IWr8J)...

> Try `count_ones`. As you can see it uses the popcnt instruction:

```
julia> code_native(count_ones,(Int64,))
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
Filename: int.jl
Source line: 192
    push    RBP
    mov RBP, RSP
Source line: 192
    popcnt  RAX, RDI
    pop RBP
    ret
```

Is your question in any way related to the Hacker News buzz about [Replacing a 32-bit loop count variable with 64-bit introduces crazy performance deviations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-count-variable-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance)?

Comment: Hey, your answer as edited is clearly acceptable since it has been edited by a moderator, but you recommended I learn from meta, so I found this: “Provide a link to the original page or answer”, and “Quote only the relevant portion”. HTH. http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: My concerns are the same as those expressed in this Meta question (thanks for recommending I educate myself there): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270522/helping-users-who-are-unable-unwilling-to-google